# Announcing the June 2019 topic challenge: Elizabethan Prose

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

In accordance with our [meta agreement](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/571/2191) to have topic challenges, and since the [list of suggestions](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/596/2191) has a single highest-voted entry at the start of this month (+6, -1), it is time to announce the next topic challenge! Throughout **June 2019**, our topic challenge, [proposed](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1032/2191) by [Christophe Strobbe](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2191/), will be

> ### Elizabethan Prose.

---

**What's a topic challenge?**

See the meta posts linked above, and also [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/340816). In short, during June we should all try to read any stories, novels, pamphlets or other prose work that are part of [Elizabethan literature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elizabethan_literature) (i.e. published between 1558 and 1603).

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, but those who participate will be forever remembered in the [annals](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1099/2191) of our history. And of course it goes without saying that questions on other works are more than welcome during June too; they just won't count as part of this topic challenge.

Below is the original presentation of this topic challenge, which contains several reading suggestions:

> Elizabethan **prose fiction** is a relatively neglected genre compared to drama (Shakespeare, Marlowe etc.) and poetry (Shakespeare, Spenser, Sidney, etc.). It includes works such as
>
> - [*Euphues: The Anatomy of Wit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphues) (1578) and *Euphues and His England* (1580) by John Lyly (leading to the term "euphuism", which refers to a mannered prose style);
> - [*The Unfortunate Traveller*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Unfortunate_Traveller), a picaresque novel, and [*Pierce Penniless*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierce_Penniless), a prose satire, by Thomas Nashe;
> - *A Discourse of the Adventures of Master FJ* by [George Gascoigne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Gascoigne);
> - [*Pandosto: The Triumph of Time*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandosto) (a prose remance that Shakespeare used as a source for *The Winter's Tale*) by Robert Greene; and
> - *Jack of Newbury* by [Thomas Deloney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Deloney).
>
> The term "novel" is hard to apply to these works. Elizabethan prose also includes **non-fiction** such as [George Puttenham's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Puttenham) *The Arte of English Poesie* (an influential handbook on poetry and rhetoric), *The School of Abuse* by [Stephen Gosson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Gosson) and [*An Apology for Poetry*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/An_Apology_for_Poetry) by Philip Sidney.
>
> There was **travel writing** by people such as [Richard Hakluyt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Hakluyt), [Thomas Coryat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Coryat) and [James Davis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Davis_(mariner)).
>
> Elizabethan authors also wrote **tracts and pamphlets**, such as [*Greene's Groats-Worth of Wit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greene%27s_Groats-Worth_of_Wit) (famous for its allusion to Shakespeare as an "upstart crow"), [*The Murder of John Brewen*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Murder_of_John_Brewen) (possibly by Thomas Kyd) and [*Have with You to Saffron-Walden*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Have_with_You_to_Saffron-Walden) by Thomas Nashe.
>
> Finally, [*Of the Lawes of Ecclesiastical Politie*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Hooker#Of_the_Lawes_of_Ecclesiastical_Politie) by Richard Hooker is a great piece of prose characterised by a dignity that I have not yet seen anywhere else.

**What's next?**

- Vote [here](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/596/2191) for the next topic challenge, or propose your own!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**List of [all questions posted](https://literature.stackexchange.com/search?q=+created%3A2019-06-01..2019-06-30+is%3Aquestion) in June 2019**

- [What sort of "relief of the poor" is Thomas Deloney alluding to?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/11142/) by [Christophe Strobbe](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2191/) (2 votes, 44 views)
- [What is a Cawdle?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/11176/) by [Christophe Strobbe](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2191/) (3 votes, 150 views, HNQ on 14 June)
- [What is the figurative meaning of "were you not borne at home"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/11183/) by [Christophe Strobbe](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2191/) (2 votes, 50 views)
- [What does Hodgekins' "Northerne speech" mean?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/11189/) by [Christophe Strobbe](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2191/) (3 votes, 62 views)
- [What sort of nemiphar's oil provided protection against torpedoes?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/11194/) by [Christophe Strobbe](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2191/) (4 votes, 28 views)
- [What does ketha mean?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/11207/) by [Christophe Strobbe](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2191/) (6 votes, 30 views)
- [Which part or quote in Cicero is Greene referring to?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/11212/) by [Christophe Strobbe](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2191/) (3 votes, 20 views)
- [Which part of Propertius' Elegies is Castania referring to?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/11219/) by [Christophe Strobbe](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2191/) (4 votes, 28 views)
- [What work or story about Lampana and Cleophila is Robert Greene referring to?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/11221/) by [Christophe Strobbe](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2191/) (4 votes, 19 views)
- [What does Mother Cornelius tub refer to?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/11230/) by [Christophe Strobbe](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2191/) (3 votes, 22 views)
- [What does "card" in the title "Gwydonius; The Card of Fancie" mean?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/11236/) by [Christophe Strobbe](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2191/) (3 votes, 31 views)
- [Where did Thomas Nashe get the Latin quote he attributes to Epicharmus?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/11243/) by [Christophe Strobbe](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2191/) (2 votes, 16 views)
- [Who were the snake-eating Candians that Nashe is referring to?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/11248/) by [Christophe Strobbe](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2191/) (1 votes, 27 views)
- [What is a Pippin at Michaelmas?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/11258/) by [Christophe Strobbe](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2191/) (1 vote, 22 views)
- *add entries in the form `https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)`*

---

The **highest-voted** of these is *[What does ketha mean?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/11207/)*, with a score of 6 at the end of the month.

The **most viewed** is *[What is a Cawdle?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/11176/)*, with approximately 150 views during the month.

This reading challenged generated **14 questions**, the same number is the [August 2018 topic challenge on Nalo Hopkinson's work](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1057/2191). It also generated **13 answers**, the highest number so far, compared to twelve for the first topic challenge and the August 2018 topic challenge.