# Announcing the August–September 2021 topic challenge: Munshi Premchand

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

In accordance with our [meta agreement to have topic challenges](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/571/2191)
and a later [meta agreement to have topic challenges lasting for two months and overlapping by one month](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1175/2191),
it is time to announce the August–September 2021 topic challenge.

Based on the number of votes (+4, resulting in a four-way tie) and our [rules for selecting a topic challenge among those that have the same number of votes](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1432/2191), the next topic challenge will be

> **Munshi Premchand (Dhanpat Rai Shrivastava)**

(In the [old suggestions thread, Munschi Premchand](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1071/2191) was suggested before Maltese literature.)

---

**What's a topic challenge?**

See the meta posts linked above, and also [this main Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/340816).
In short, during August and September 2021 you are invited to try to get hold of one of the works of
[Munshi Premchand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premchand) and ask questions about it.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, and questions on other works are more than welcome during August and September too;
they just won't count as part of this topic challenge.

**How can I take part?**

By getting hold of one of the works of Munshi Premchand and asking good questions about it.
Questions about these works should be tagged with [premchand](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/premchand), [urdu-literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/urdu-literature) for works originally written in Urdu (before 1914) or [hindi-literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hindi-literature) for works originally written in Hindi (starting in 1914), and a tag for the work (if it is a book-length work).
We'll keep a list of all such questions in an answer to this meta post.

Below is [Tsundoku's](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/tsundoku)
[presentation](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1239/2191):

> Since this site needs more questions about non-Western literature, I'm submitting a proposal for one of the most important 20th-century authors from India. [Munshi Premchand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premchand) (1880 – 1936) is not well known in the West, even though he "**is regarded as one of the foremost Hindi writers of the early twentieth century**" (Wikipedia).
> He published novels, short stories and plays; not all of them have been translated into English.
>
> - His first major novel, [*Bazaar-e-Husn*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bazaar-e-Husn), (1924) was translated into English as *Sevasadan* ([Oxford University Press, 2005](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/sevasadan-9780195696585)).
> - [*Nirmala*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nirmala_(novel)) (1927) was translated into English in 2001 ([Oxford University Press](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/nirmala-9780195658262)).
> - [*Gaban*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaban_(novel)) (1931) was translated as *Gaban: The Stolen Jewels* ([Oxford University Press, 2002](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/gaban-9780195662634)).
> - The novel [*Karmabhoomi*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karmabhoomi) (1932) was translated as *Karmabhumi* ([Oxford University Press, 2008](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/karmabhumi-9780195696660)).
> - The novel [*Godaan*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godaan) (1936) was translated into English as *The Gift of a Cow*, into French as *Godan: Le don d'une vache* (L'Hermattan, 2006) and into German as *Godan oder die Opfergabe* (Manesse, 1979, where the author is identified as Premacanda).
> - Penguin Books India published [*The Complete Short Stories*](https://penguin.co.in/book/fiction/the-complete-short-stories-vol-4/) in four volumes in 2017 (but none of his other works).
> - For a selection of short stories, see *The Illustrated Premchand: Selected Short Stories* ([Oxford University Press, 2006](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/the-illustrated-premchand-9780195684186)).
>
> Some of these translations were published on the occasion of the 125th anniversary of Premchand's birth or shortly thereafter. There are also a few [German translations](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premchand#Ausgaben_in_%C3%9Cbersetzungen).
>
> A [monograph by Madan Gopal](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.186631), published in 1944, is now available on Archive.org.

**What's next?**

- [Vote for the next topic challenge](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1238/2191) (September–October), or propose your own!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**List of [all questions posted](https://literature.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bpremchand%5D+created%3A2021-08-01..2021-09-30+is%3Aquestion) in this topic challenge**

1. [Has the text of Premchand's banned short-story collection Soz-e-Watan survived?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/19443/) by [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/tsundoku), 01/09/2021 (1 answer).
2. [Why was 50 considered old in Premchand's day?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/19569/why-was-50-considered-old-in-premchands-day) by [EJoshuaS - Reinstate Monica](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/ejoshuas-reinstate-monica), 17/09/2021 (2 answers).
3. [Why was Bhungi poor in spite of having an apparently thriving business?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/19570/why-was-bhungi-poor-in-spite-of-having-an-apparently-thriving-business) by [EJoshuaS - Reinstate Monica](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/ejoshuas-reinstate-monica), 17/09/2021 (1 answer).
4. [What did it mean for Pandit Udaybhan Pandey to own the entire village?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/19571/what-did-it-mean-for-pandit-udaybhan-pandey-to-own-the-entire-village) by [EJoshuaS - Reinstate Monica](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/ejoshuas-reinstate-monica), 17/09/2021 (2 answers, including a deleted one).
5. [Who are all these writers referred to by Premchand?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/19661/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17), 28/09/2021 (1 answer).
6. [Which Premchand stories are written in Hindi and which in Urdu?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/19673/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17), 29/09/2021 (1 answer).

---

The **highest-voted** and **most viewed** of these is [Has the text of Premchand's banned short-story collection Soz-e-Watan survived?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/19443/) by [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/tsundoku), with a score of **7** and approximately **260** views during the months of August and September.

Each question received at least one answer before the end of September.