Announcing the April–May 2024 topic challenge: Carlo Goldoni
In accordance with our meta agreement to have topic challenges
and a later meta agreement to have topic challenges lasting for two months and overlapping by one month,
it is time to announce the April – May 2024 topic challenge.
Based on the number of votes (+5/-1), the third topic challenge fully in 2024 will be:

Carlo Goldoni


What's a topic challenge?
See the meta posts linked above, and also this main meta post. In short, during April and May 2024 you are invited to try to read at least one work by Carlo Goldoni and ask questions about it.
Participation is not obligatory in any sense, and questions on other works are more than welcome during April and May too; they just won't count as part of this topic challenge.
How can I take part?
By getting hold of some works of Carlo Goldoni and asking (or answering!) good questions about them. Questions about these works should be tagged with carlo-goldoni and italian-language and other tags as appropriate. We'll keep a list of all such questions in an answer to this meta post.
Below is Tsundoku's
presentation of the topic:

Carlo Goldoni (1707 – 1793) was a playwright and librettist who lived in the Republic of Venice. His libretti include one for La finta semplice, an opera Mozart composed at the age of 12, and one for Vivaldi's opera Griselda. His best-known play is possibly The Servant of Two Masters, which draws on the tradition of the commedia dell'arte.
Online versions of some of his works include the following:

The Servant of Two Masters, translated with an introduction by Edward J. Dent (1928) (Project Gutenberg)
The Liar (on Archive.org)
Inquisitive women (libretto, on Archive.org)
Die neugierigen Frauen (German translation of the same libretto)
The Comic Theatre (non-fiction, on Archive.org)
The Mistress of the Inn (La locandiera in Italian), considered the masterpiece of Goldoni
The coffee shop (La bottega del caffè in Italian, on Archive.org).


Other interesting sources of information are the following:

Booklet from Carlo Goldoni's House museum, which contains lots of interesting informations about Carlo Goldoni and his plays and texts. This is the website of the museum.

What's next?

Vote for the next topic challenge (May–June), or propose your own topic!
Feel free to edit links into this post if you find some good resources of Goldoni works available to read online.


Not sure that all the questions should be tagged [tag:italian-language]: some of the Goldoni's works were written in Venetian and some other in French.

List of all questions posted in this topic challenge

Did Goldoni decide to set the action of "La bottega del caffè" during a Venetian carnival for the sake of verisimilitude? by Charo, 07/04/2024.

"La guerra" by Goldoni: why was it about waiting for a war commissioner to become rich? by Charo, 14/04/2024 (two answers).

Have Bertolt Brecht's plays been influenced by Goldoni's "La guerra"? by Charo, 15/04/2024.

Is the fact that "La bottega del caffè" is an ensemble comedy an innovation by Goldoni?
 by Charo, 10/05/2024.

Why would Goldoni have wanted to allude to a treatise on thermal waters in "La bottega del caffè"? by Charo, 29/05/2024.



The highest-voted of these are:

"La guerra" by Goldoni: why was it about waiting for a war commissioner to become rich?
Have Bertolt Brecht's plays been influenced by Goldoni's "La guerra"?

each with a score of 4 at the end of May.
The most viewed is "La guerra" by Goldoni: why was it about waiting for a war commissioner to become rich?, with approximately 126 views by the end of May.
1 question received at least one answer. Four out of five questions received no answer.

Reviews submitted to our Tumblr blog: none.
