# Announcing the May–June 2020 topic challenge: Guy de Maupassant

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

In accordance with our [meta agreement to have topic challenges](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/571/17) and a later [meta agreement to have topic challenges lasting for two months and overlapping by one month](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1175/17), it is time to announce the **May–June 2020 topic challenge**.

Based on the number of votes (in the [***old*** suggestions thread](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/596/17) - the new one hasn't had time to gather many votes yet), the fifth topic challenge of 2020 will be

> **the works of Guy de Maupassant**

---

**What's a topic challenge?**

See the meta posts linked above, and also [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/340816). In short, during May–June 2020 we should all try to read one or more works by [**Guy de Maupassant**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guy_de_Maupassant).

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, but those who participate will be forever remembered in the [annals](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1099/2191) of our history.
And of course it goes without saying that questions on other works are more than welcome during May and June too; they just won't count as part of this topic challenge.

**How can I take part?**

By getting hold of any of Guy de Maupassant's stories and asking good questions about them. These questions should be tagged with [guy-de-maupassant](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guy-de-maupassant) and [french-literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/french-literature), and either [short-stories](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-stories) or a specific-work tag for longer works. We'll keep a list of all such questions in an answer to this meta post.

Below is the [original presentation](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1185/17) of this topic challenge, which contains several useful links:

> [Guy de Maupassant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guy_de_Maupassant) (1850 – 1893) was probably the most important 19th-century French author of [short stories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guy_de_Maupassant_bibliography#Short_stories). Some of them are very well known, e.g. [Boule de Suif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boule_de_Suif).
>
> His stories are now in the public domain. Many of his stories are available on [Wikisource in French](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Auteur:Guy_de_Maupassant). A number of [English translations are available on Wikisource](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Author:Guy_de_Maupassant). <del>Other English translations are available at [ebooks@Adelaide](https://ebooks.adelaide.edu.au/m/maupassant/guy/).</del> The complete collection of his short stories is available in English at [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/3090) (which currently blocks users from Germany).
>
> For a printed selection, see for example, [*Guy de Maupassant's Selected Works*](https://wwnorton.com/books/9780393923278) (W. W. Norton, 2016; 448 pages).
>
> The online availability of English translations should make participation in the reading challenge easier.  Even though we already have a few questions about [guy-de-maupassant](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guy-de-maupassant), there are still dozens of his stories that have never been discussed.

This is a particularly easy author to "dip in" to his works, because he wrote many **short stories** which are old enough to be **available online** freely and legally, even in translation.

**What's next?**

- The April-May 2020 topic challenge, [The Stranger / Meursault](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1229/17), is still ongoing. So is the March-April 2020 one, [R. K. Narayan](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1222/17), for another week or so. It's not too late to participate in them too!
- Vote [here](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1238/17) (new thread) for the next topic challenge (June–July), or propose your own in an answer there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**List of [all questions posted](https://literature.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5Bguy-de-maupassant%5D%20created%3a2020-05-01..2020-06-30%20is%3aquestion) in this topic challenge**

1. [What political leanings are being described for Monsieur Carre-Lamadon?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/14217/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17), 7/5/2020 (2 answers).
2. <s>https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/14238/17 by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17), 8/5/2020</s>
3. [Which short stories are falsely attributed to Guy de Maupassant, and why?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/14259/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17), 10/5/2020 (1 answer).
4. [What does it mean to "unmoor criticism"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/14275/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17), 11/5/2020 (2 answers).
5. [What is the difference between souteneur and proxénète in Maupassant's Bel-Ami?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/14324/) by [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/), 17.05.2020 (2 answers).
6. [What is so Balzacian about Mr. Walter's words to Mr. Montelin in Maupassant's Bel-Ami?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/14366/) by [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/), 19.05.2020.
7. [Is Maupassant referring to a ranking of duellists or shooters that existed in late nineteenth-century France?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/14373/) by [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/), 20.05.2020.
8. [What does it mean to have teeth in the English style?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/14388/) by [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/), 21.05.2020 (1 answer).
9. [In Maupassant's Bel-Ami, why would it be compromising for a magistrate to have been in (the) mixed committees?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/14407/) by [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/), 23.05.2020 (1 answer).
10. [Is Lambert-Sarrazin's moustache speech in Bel-Ami an allusion to a real speech?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/14446/) by [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/), 27.05.2020.
11. [What is the nature of the relationship between Madeleine and the Comte de Vaudrec in Bel-Ami?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/14455/) by [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/), 28.05.2020 (1 answer).
12. [Did Maupassant adapt the style and content of his stories to the newspapers that published them?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/14512/) by [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/), 06.06.2020.
13. [How did contemporary female readers respond to the sexual violence in the Contes de la Bécasse?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/14589/) by [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/), 13.06.2020.
14. [For Maupassant, were women more inclined to imitate others than men?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/14617/) by [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/), 16.06.2020.
15. [Was Maupassant's interest in madness and the supernatural linked to his own mental health?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/14665/) by [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/), 20.06.2020.
16. [How did Maupassant's contemporaries respond to his play Une répétition?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/14698/) by [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/), 22.06.2020.
17. [Did the Eiffel Tower feature in any of Maupassant's stories or novels?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/14761/) by [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/), 29.06.2020 (1 answer).
18. [How did Maupassant's contemporaries respond to his play Musotte?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/14777/) by [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/), 29.06.2020.
19. [Did Maupassant and Richepin know each other?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/14788/) by [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/), 30.06.2020.

---

The **highest-voted** of these is [Which short stories are falsely attributed to Guy de Maupassant, and why?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/14259/17), with a score of **5** at the end of June.

The **most viewed** is [What does it mean to "unmoor criticism"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/14275/17), with approximately **237** views during the months of May and June. (It [hit](https://literature.stackexchange.com/posts/14275/revisions) the HNQ list.)

Comment: If the second question was posted during the challenge because the work it asks about was erroneously attributed to Maupassant, why would it not count as part of the challenge?

Comment: @verbose I suppose that gets down a philosophical question on whether we care more about intent or effect. The question was *meant* to be part of the topic challenge, but in fact it didn't contribute to the set of Maupassant questions on the site. I compromised by leaving it in the list but crossed out.