# Announcing the September–October 2020 topic challenge: Nick Joaquin

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

In accordance with our [meta agreement to have topic challenges](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/571/2191)
and a later [meta agreement to have topic challenges lasting for two months and overlapping by one month](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1175/2191),
it is time to announce the September–October 2020 topic challenge.

Based on the number of votes, the ninth topic challenge of the year 2020 will be

> ***the works of Nick Joaquin***

---

**What's a topic challenge?**

See the meta posts linked above, and also [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/340816).
In short, during September and October 2020 you are invited to try to read at least one work by
the Filipino writer Nick Joaquin and ask questions about it.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, and questions on other works are more than welcome during September and October too;
they just won't count as part of this topic challenge.

**How can I take part?**

By getting hold of the one or more works by Nick Joaquin and asking good questions about it (or them).
Questions about these works should be tagged with [nick-joaquin](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nick-joaquin) and
either the work's title (for book-length works) or [short-stories](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-stories) (for short stories, as the name implies).
We'll keep a list of all such questions in an answer to this meta post.

Below is [Tsundoku's](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2191)
[presentation](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1246/2191):

> [Nick Joaquin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nick_Joaquin) (1917 – 2004) was a Filipino journalist and author whose works include the following:
>
> - [*A Portrait of the Artist as Filipino*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Portrait_of_the_Artist_as_Filipino) (1950), which is regarded as the "national play of the Philippines",
> - [*The Woman Who Had Two Navels*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Woman_Who_Had_Two_Navels) (1961), which is considered a classic in Philippine literature (reprinted by Penguin in 2017: [*The Woman Who Had Two Navels and Tales of the Tropical Gothic*](https://www.penguin.co.uk/books/305045/the-woman-who-had-two-navels-and-tales-of-the-tropical-gothic/9780143130710.html)),
> - [*Cave and Shadows*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cave_and_Shadows) (1983), a novel set during [Ferdinand Marcos’s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferdinand_Marcos) martial law in the Philippines,
> - ["The Summer Solstice"](http://malacanang.gov.ph/75510-the-summer-solstice-by-nick-joaquin/), a short story, and
> - ["May Day Eve"](http://www.seasite.niu.edu/Tagalog/Literature/Short%20Stories/May%20Day%20Eve.htm), a short story.

See also

- [A Heritage of Smallness by Nick Joaquin](https://freethinking.me/essays/a-heritage-of-smallness-by-nick-joaquin-2) on the website freethinking.me (04/03/2014);
- [Nick Joaquin and His Enduring Legacy](https://www.spot.ph/arts-culture/arts-culture-peopleparties/77817/nick-joaquin-life-src-esquire-sa4349-20190512-src-esquireph-lfrm) by Mario Alvaro Limos (12/05/2019).

**What's next?**

- [Vote for the next topic challenge](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1238/2191) (October–November), or propose your own!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**List of [all questions posted](https://literature.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5Bnick-joaquin%5D%20created%3a2020-09-01..2020-10-31%20is%3aquestion) in this topic challenge**

1. [What do Connie's two navels represent?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/16020/) by [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/), 18/10/2020 (4 votes, 39 views).
2. [Who are/were the man and woman in Nick Joaquin's "May Day Eve"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/16083/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17), 23/10/2020 (1 vote, 30 views, 1 answer).
3. [What does 'por bida man guid' mean?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/16084/) by [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/), 23/10/2020 (1 vote, 26 views).
4. [What does ‘Kung mapatay di madeadball ’ mean?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/16085/) by [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/), 24/10/2020 (2 votes, 21 views).
5. [What does cuatro cantos refer to?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/16100/) by [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/), 26/10/2020 (2 votes, 28 views, 1 answer).
6. [What is the literary effect of such long opening and closing sentences in "May Day Eve"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/16116/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17), 27/10/2020 (2 votes, 13 views).
7. [Does the Order of Melchizedek's professed goal to bring the Vatican Council to the masses refer to a historical reality?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/16164/) by [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/), 31/10/2020 (2 votes, 13 views).

- *add entries in the form `https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>), dd/mm/2020.`*

---

The **highest-voted** of these is [What do Connie's two navels represent?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/16020/), with a score of 4 at the end of October.

The **most viewed** is [What do Connie's two navels represent?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/16020/), with approximately 39 views during the months of September and October.

Two questions received an answer before the end of the challenge.