# Announcing the November–December 2020 topic challenge: Ko Un

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

In accordance with our [meta agreement to have topic challenges](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/571/17) and a later [meta agreement to have topic challenges lasting for two months and overlapping by one month](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1175/17), it is time to announce the **November–December 2020 topic challenge**.

Based on the number of votes, the last topic challenge fully in 2020 will be

### **the works of Ko Un**

---

**What's a topic challenge?**

See the meta posts linked above, and also [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/340816). In short, during November–December 2020 we should all try to read one or more works by [**Ko Un**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ko_Un).

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, but those who participate will be forever remembered in the [annals](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1446/17) of our history.
And of course it goes without saying that questions on other works are more than welcome during November and December too; they just won't count as part of this topic challenge.

**How can I take part?**

By getting hold of any of Ko Un's stories or poems and asking good questions about them. These questions should be tagged with [ko-un](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ko-un) and [korean-literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/korean-literature), and either [poetry](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry) or a specific-work tag for longer works. We'll keep a list of all such questions in an answer to this meta post.

Below is [Eddie Kal's original presentation](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1419/17) of this topic challenge, which contains some useful links:

> [Ko Un](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ko_Un) is a Korean poet who has remained a top contender for the Nobel Prize in Literature.
>
> [Little Pilgrim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Pilgrim) could be an easy start. Some of his short poems are available online; people can get a taste at [Poetry Foundation](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poets/ko-un-56d207070306a) and on the [Brief Poems blog](https://briefpoems.wordpress.com/tag/ko-un/).

**What's next?**

- The September-October 2020 topic challenge, [Nick Joaquin](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1372/17), is still ongoing. So is the October-November 2020 one, [Rabindranath Tagore](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1433/17), starting today.
- Vote [here](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1238/17) for the next topic challenge, or propose your own in an answer there!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**List of [all questions posted](https://literature.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bko-un%5D+created%3A2020-11-01..2020-12-31+is%3Aquestion) in this topic challenge**

1. [In Ko Un's short poem "In the very middle of the road", why does the narrator take a different path?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/16508/58) by [Mithical](https://literature.stackexchange.com/u/58), 29/11/2020 (2 upvotes, 44 views, no answer).
2. [What's the connection between millennia of time travel and waiting for a bus?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/16893/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/u/17), 23/12/2020 (4 upvotes, 315 views, 2 answers, HNQ on 23/12/2020).
3. [Why does isolating "there" on its own line sound less emphatic in Korean than English?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/16901) by [bobble](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/11259), 23/12/2020 (4 upvotes, 39 views, no answer).
4. [Is there any significance to the lemons and the port in Ko Un's "Asking the Way"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/16907/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/u/17), 24/12/2020 (3 upvotes, 15 views, no answer).
5. [Ko Un's "Around Unmun Temple at Ch'Eongdo"](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/16947/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/u/17), 28/12/2020 (3 upvotes, 18 views, no answer).
6. [Where is "Keumgang-Gul / Diamond Cave"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/16985/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/u/17), 31/12/2020 (1 upvote, 13 views, no answer).

---

The **highest-voted** of these were [What's the connection between millennia of time travel and waiting for a bus?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/16893/) and [Why does isolating "there" on its own line sound less emphatic in Korean than English?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/16901), both with a score of 4 at the end of December.

The **most viewed** was [What's the connection between millennia of time travel and waiting for a bus?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/16893/), which went HNQ and received approximately 315 views during the months of November and December.

This question also received two answers and was the only one that received any answers.