# Announcing the October–November 2020 topic challenge: Rabindranath Tagore

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

In accordance with our [meta agreement to have topic challenges](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/571/2191)
and a later [meta agreement to have topic challenges lasting for two months and overlapping by one month](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1175/2191),
it is time to announce the October–November 2020 topic challenge.

Based on the number of votes (5 upvotes, one downvote), the tenth topic challenge of the year 2020 will be

> **the works of Rabindranath Tagore**

---

**What's a topic challenge?**

See the meta posts linked above, and also [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/340816).
In short, during October and November 2020 you are invited to try to read at least one work by
the Bengali polymath Rabindranath Tagore and ask questions about it.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, and questions on other works are more than welcome during October and November too;
they just won't count as part of this topic challenge.

**How can I take part?**

By getting hold of one or more works by Rabindranath Tagore and asking good questions about it (or them).
Questions about these works should be tagged with [rabindranath-tagore](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rabindranath-tagore) and
either the work's title (for book-length works) or [short-stories](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-stories) (for short stories, as the name implies).
We'll keep a list of all such questions in an answer to this meta post.

Below is [Peter Shor's](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1152)
[presentation](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1248/2191):

> I would like to suggest [Rabindranath Tagore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabindranath_Tagore) (1861—1941), an important Bengali writer who wrote poems, short stories, and novels.
>
> This is in part a response to the suggestion of Munshi Premchand (1880—1936), a Hindi writer whose works seem quite difficult to get in English. I expect that choosing Premchand for a challenge would fail for the same reason some of the challenges before the reboot did: the author is too obscure and people will not be able to find his books.
>
> Tagore is an Indian writer from roughly the same period. However, his work appears to be much more available in English: many of his poems can be found on the internet, and several of his plays and short story collections, and his novel *The Home and the World* are available from Project Gutenberg. Other novels of his have also been translated, although I don't know whether they are available online.

Further information thanks to [user37920](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/users/10622/user37920):

- Tagore received the Nobel Prize in Literature in 1913 for his poems and collections of poetry, largely [*Gitanjali*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gitanjali) / [*Song Offerings*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Song_Offerings).
- The national anthem of India, ["Jana Gana Mana"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jana_Gana_Mana), was originally composed as "Bharoto Bhagyo Bidhata" in Bengali by Rabindranath Tagore.
- The national anthem of Bangladesh, ["Amar Sonar Bangla"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amar_Sonar_Bangla), was also written and composed by Tagore, making him the only musician to have composed the national anthem for two sovereign countries.

See also:

- [Rabindranath Tagore on Wikisource](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Author:Rabindranath_Tagore): works such as [*The Home and the World*](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Home_and_the_World) (novel, 1916), [*The Post Office*](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Post_Office) (play, 1914), [*The Hungry Stones and Other Stories*](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Hungry_Stones_and_Other_Stories).
- [Rabindranath Tagore on AllPoetry.com](https://allpoetry.com/Rabindranath-Tagore).
- [Tagore, Rabindranath, 1861-1941](https://onlinebooks.library.upenn.edu/webbin/book/browse?type=lcsubc&key=Tagore%2c%20Rabindranath%2c%201861%2d1941) on The Online Books Page (University of Pennsylvania).
- [Rabindranath Tagore - Bibliography](https://www.nobelprize.org/prizes/literature/1913/tagore/bibliography/) on NobelPrize.org.
- [Tagore Web](https://www.tagoreweb.in/).
- [*Selected Short Stories*](https://www.penguin.co.uk/books/17441/selected-short-stories/9780140449839.html). Translated by William Radice. Penguin, 2005. (352 pages).
- [*The Essential Tagore*](https://www.hup.harvard.edu/catalog.php?isbn=9780674417045), edited by Fakrul Alam and Radha Chakravarty. Harvard University Press, 2014. (864 pages).
- [*The Definitive Tagore*](http://rupapublications.co.in/books/the-definitive-tagore/). Rupa Publications, 2017. (664 pages). This volume contains the Nobel Prize Acceptance Speech, *My Boyhood Days* (1940), *The Post Office* (1914), *Chokher Bali* (1903), *Gitanjali* (1910), *The Home and the World* (1916), "Nationalism in India", *Glimpses of Bengal* (1920) and five short stories.

**What's next?**

- [Vote for the next topic challenge](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1238/2191) (November–December), or propose your own!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**List of [all questions posted](https://literature.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Brabindranath-tagore%5D+created%3A2020-10-01..2020-11-30+is%3Aquestion) in this topic challenge**

1. [Why does the narrator in Tagore's story call the Cabuliwallah's daughter "Parbati"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/15884/) by [verbose](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/289/), 05/10/2020 (self-answered on the same day; two answers in total).
2. [Who is Tagore's "Cruel Kindness" addressed to?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/15885/) by [Mithical](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/58/), 05/10/2020 (one answer).
3. [Why was the narrator left alone on the shore in Tagore's "Sonar Tari"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/15887) by [user37920](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/10622/user37920), 05/10/2020 (one answer, which was awarded a 100-reps bounty).
4. [What does "raised waves in my mind" mean in Tagore's "At the End of the Day"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/15899/) by [Mithical](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/58/), 06/10/2020 (one answer).
5. [Why do the prayers stop in Tagore's "A Dream"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/15919/58) by [Mithical](https://literature.stackexchange.com/u/58), 07/10/2020 (two answers).
6. [In Tagore's "Along the Way", who is the entity that the "your touch" is referring to?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/15921/) by [Mithical](https://literature.stackexchange.com/u/58), 08/10/2020 (one answer).
7. [Is Rabindranth Tagore talking about the actual wave nature of light here in Gitanjali?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/16068/17) by [Knight](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/8723/knight), 22/10/2020 (one answer)).
8. [Why would the indigo factory's steward be a messenger of death?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/16118/) by [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/), 27/10/2020. (one answer; 100 reputation bounty awarded by Rand al'Thor, active 11-17/11/2020.)
9. [When did Tagore write "The Victory"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/16174/) by [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/), 01/11/2020 (one answer).
10. [What is the original source of Rabindranath Tagore's "Endless Time"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/16222/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17), 05/11/2020. (two answers; 100 reputation bounty awarded by Peter Shor, active 07-08/11/2020.)
11. [What language was Tagore's "This Dog" written in?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/16256/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17), 08/11/2020 (one answer).
12. [What is the significance of "southern" in Tagore's poem "A Hundred Years From Now"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/16323/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17), 12/11/2020 (one answer).
13. [How good was Rabindranath Tagore's English, in general?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/16342/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17), 14/11/2020 (one answer).
14. <s>[Is Tagore's Chokher Bali a novel that illustrates the workings of mimetic desire?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/16360/)  by [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/), 16/11/2020.</s> Deleted on 17/11/2020.
15. [What is the relationship between Tagore's poems and his song lyrics?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/16382) by [verbose](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/289/), 17/11/2020.
16. [How does Irishness affect subject-formation and national identification in Kipling's *Kim* and Tagore's *Gora*?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/16399/17) by [verbose](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/289/), 20/11/2020.
17. [Does Bankim Chandra Chatterjee's novel Vishabriksha have a special meaning in Tagore's Chokher Bali?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/16405/) by [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/), 21/11/2020 (one answer).
18. [Why does Tagore not consistently use ‘thou’ when addressing the supreme being in Gitanjali?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/16420/) by [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/), 23/11/2020.
19. [What are the originals of the poems Tagore has translated from English into Bengali?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/16425/17) by [verbose](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/289/), 23/11/2020.
20. [What does the sword represent in poem 52 of Tagore's English Gitanjali?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/16501/) by [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/), 28/11/2020.
21. [Who classified Rabindranath Tagore's lyrics into the six standard categories?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/16518/17) by [verbose](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/289/), 30/11/2020 (one answer, self-answered).
22. [What song is mai chhoro brajaki basari?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/16521/) by [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/), 30/11/2020 (no answer during the challenge period; one answer submitted on the next day).

x. *add entries in the form `https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>), dd/mm/2020.`*

---

The **highest-voted** of these are [Why does the narrator in Tagore's story call the Cabuliwallah's daughter "Parbati"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/15884/17) and [What is the significance of "southern" in Tagore's poem "A Hundred Years From Now"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/16323/17) and [How good was Rabindranath Tagore's English, in general?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/16342/17), each with a score of **5** at the end of November.

The **most viewed** is [Why does the narrator in Tagore's story call the Cabuliwallah's daughter "Parbati"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/15884/17) (HNQ), with approximately **170** views during the months of October and November. Runner-ups are [Why was the narrator left alone on the shore in Tagore's "Sonar Tari"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/15887/17) with approximately 160 views, and [Who classified Rabindranath Tagore's lyrics into the six standard categories?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/16518/17) (HNQ) which had 169 views on 1 December.

15 questions received an answer, and 18 answers were submitted in total during the challenge.