# Announcing the February–March 2021 topic challenge: Os Lusíadas / The Lusiads

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

In accordance with our [meta agreement to have topic challenges](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/571/17) and a later [meta agreement to have topic challenges lasting for two months and overlapping by one month](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1175/17), it is time to announce the **February–March 2021 topic challenge**.

Based on the number of votes in the [proposals thread](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1238/17) (+6), the second topic challenge of 2021 will be the Portuguese epic poem

### ***Os Lusíadas* (*The Lusiads*).**

---

**What's a topic challenge?**

See the meta posts linked above, and also [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/340816). In short, during February–March 2021 we should all try to read **[*Os Lusíadas*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Os_Lus%C3%ADadas)**.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, but those who participate will be forever remembered in the [annals](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1516/17) of our history. And of course it goes without saying that questions about other works are more than welcome during those months too; they just won't count as part of this topic challenge.

**How can I take part?**

By getting hold of *Os Lusíadas*, in any language you like, and asking good questions about it. These questions should be tagged with [the-lusiads](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-lusiads) and [portuguese-literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/portuguese-literature) and [poetry](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry), and other tags if appropriate. We'll keep a list of all such questions in an answer to this meta post.

Below is [Tsundoku's original presentation](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1258/17) of this topic challenge, which contains some useful links:

> [*Os Lusíadas*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Os_Lus%C3%ADadas) by  Luís Vaz de Camões is one great classics of Portuguese literature. This epic poem, first published in 1572, "celebrates the discovery of a sea route to India by the Portuguese explorer Vasco da Gama (1469–1524)" (Wikipedia).
>
> The text can be easily found online, for example:
>
> - [in Portuguese on Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/etext/3333),
> - [William Julius Mickle's English translation (1776) on sacred-texts.com](https://www.sacred-texts.com/neu/lus/index.htm),
> - a [French translation from 1882 on Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/leslusiadesoules00camuoft),
> - [scanned versions of the 1572 Portuguese edition on Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Os_Lus%C3%ADadas,_1572?uselang=de) (and elsewhere).
>
> For translations available in print, see for example
>
> - *The Lusiads*. Translated by William Atkinson. [Penguin](https://www.penguin.co.uk/books/34683/the-lusiads/9780140440263.html), 1952. (256 pages). This is a prose translation with a 30-page introduction.
> - *The Lusiads*. Translated by Landeg White. [Oxford University Press](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/the-lusiads-9780199539963), 1997. (288 pages). This is a verse translation with a 12-page introduction, a select bibliography, maps and (at the back of the book) explanatory notes.

**What's next?**

- The December 2020 - January 2021 topic challenge, [literary theory](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1473/17), is still ongoing. The January-February 2021 one, [Theodor Fontane](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1490/17), is starting imminently.
- Vote [here](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1238/17) for the next topic challenge, or propose your own in an answer there!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**List of [all questions posted](https://literature.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bthe-lusiads%5D+created%3A2021-02-01..2021-03-31+is%3Aquestion) in this topic challenge**

1. [Since when do the Portuguese regard The Lusiads as their national epic?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/17935/) by [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/), 11.03.2021 (6 votes, 0 answers; appr. 33 view).
2. [Which passages in Manuel de Faria e Sousa's commentary on The Lusiads caused his temporary incarceration by the Inquisition?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/18015/) by [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/), 16.03.2021 (3 votes, 1 verbose answer, appr. 43 views).
3. [Where is St. Lawrence island in Africa, mentioned in Os Lusíadas](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/18030/) by [b_jonas](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/139/), 18.03.2021 (6 votes, 1 verbose answer, appr. 192 views; HNQ).
4. [What's the significance of the "Invocation to the muses of the Tagus"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/18062) by [bobble](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/11259), 20.3.2021 (4 votes, 1 verbose answer, appr. 34 views).
5. [What is meant by "Nysa" in the Lusiads?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/18160/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17), 27.3.2021 (3 votes, 2 answers, appr. 72 views, HNQ).
6. [Chilli peppers in fifteenth-century India?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/18180/289) by [verbose](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/289), 28.3.2021 (15 votes, 1 answer (self-answered), appr. 2000 views, HNQ).
7. [On what sources did Camões base his Os Lusíadas?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/18184/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17), 28.3.2021 (3 votes, 1 verbose answer, appr. 35 views).
8. [How does ancient Greek polytheism fit with Christianity in The Lusiads?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/18206/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17), 31.3.2021 (2 votes, 0 answers, appr. 16 views).

---

The **highest-voted** of these is [Chilli peppers in fifteenth-century India?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/18180/289), with a score of 15 at the end of March.

The **most viewed** is [Chilli peppers in fifteenth-century India?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/18180/289), with approximately 2000 views during the months of February and March.

Two questions became hot network questions. Each of the six questions that received an answer received one written by [verbose](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/289/).

Comment: Feel free to drop by [Falatório](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25826/falatorio) with any informal queries you might have about portuguese :) that you feel don't fit in the main site, [portuguese.SE](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com).