# Announcing the March–April 2021 topic challenge: Mem and Zin (Mam û Zîn)

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

In accordance with our [meta agreement to have topic challenges](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/571/17) and a later [meta agreement to have topic challenges lasting for two months and overlapping by one month](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1175/17), it is time to announce the **March–April 2021 topic challenge**.

Based on the number of votes in the [proposals thread](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1238/17) (+5), the third topic challenge of 2021 will be the Kurdish classic

### ***Mem û Zîn* (*Mem and Zin*).**

---

**What's a topic challenge?**

See the meta posts linked above, and also [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/340816). In short, during March–April 2021 we should all try to read **[*Mem û Zîn*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mem_and_Zin)**.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, but those who participate will be forever remembered in the [annals](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1521/17) of our history. And of course it goes without saying that questions about other works are more than welcome during those months too; they just won't count as part of this topic challenge.

**How can I take part?**

By getting hold of *Mem û Zîn*, in any language you like, and asking good questions about it. These questions should be tagged with [mem-and-zin](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mem-and-zin) and [ahmad-khani](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ahmad-khani) and [kurdish-literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kurdish-literature), and other tags if appropriate. We'll keep a list of all such questions in an answer to this meta post.

Below is [Rand al'Thor's original presentation](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1435/17) of this topic challenge, which contains some useful links:

> [This story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mem_and_Zin) is one of the most important works of [Kurdish literature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurdish_literature) - a language group so far entirely unrepresented on our site. It's a Romeo & Juliet style romantic tragedy, written by [Ahmad Khani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahmad_Khani) in 1692 based on oral traditions. It's been adapted into a film (in Turkish) and a TV series.
>
> - Being such an old story, it has an [English translation](https://archive.org/stream/AhmedKhaniMemAndJinTrans.BySalahSaadalla/Ahmed+Khani-Mem+and+Jin-trans.+by+Salah+Saadalla_djvu.txt) freely available online.
> - Also freely available online is an [entire book](http://bnk.institutkurde.org/images/pdf/7KS6DGQY39.pdf) *about* the story, containing various studies and analyses, uploaded to the Kurdish Institute Library.

**What's next?**

- The January–February 2021 topic challenge, [Theodor Fontane](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1490/17), and the February–March one, [*The Lusiads*](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1515/17), are currently ongoing.
- Vote [here](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1238/17) for the next topic challenge, or propose your own in an answer there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**List of [all questions posted](https://literature.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmem-and-zin%5D+created%3A2021-03-01..2021-04-30+is%3Aquestion) in this topic challenge**

1. [When was Mem and Zin / Mam û Zîn first printed?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/17968/) by [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/), 14/03/2021 (5 votes, 1 answer),
2. [When/where was "Mem and Zin" first compared to "Romeo and Juliet"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/18256/17) by [bobble](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/11259/bobble), 05/04/2021 (4 votes, no answers),
3. [What are all the love stories referred to in chapter 2 of Mem and Zin?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/18408/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17), 22/04/2021 (2 votes, 1 answer),
4. [What plight of the Kurds is suggested in Mem and Zin chapter 5?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/18416/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17), 23/04/2021 (0 votes, no answers),
5. [Where is the Kurdish principality of Botan?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/18452/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17), 25/04/2021 (two votes, 1 answer),
6. [Why did Mem/Tajdin and Zin/Siti disguise themselves for Nowruz?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/18482/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17), 29/04/2021 (1 vote, 1 answer),
7. [How does Ahmad Khani's Mem and Zin differ from the pre-existing oral tradition of the story?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/18494/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17), 30/04/2021 (0 votes, no answers).

- *add entries in the form `https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>), dd/mm/2021.`*

---

The **highest-voted** of these is [When was Mem and Zin / Mam û Zîn first printed?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/17968/), with a score of **5** at the end of April.

The **most viewed** are [When was Mem and Zin / Mam û Zîn first printed?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/17968/) and [Where is the Kurdish principality of Botan?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/18452/where-is-the-kurdish-principality-of-botan), each with approximately **40–45** views during the months of March and April. (The view counts currently shown are 43 and 40, so if you want to pick a winner it'd be the first one.)

Four out of the seven questions received an answer during the topic challenge: three of these answers were submitted by [Spagirl](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/333/spagirl), the other one by [b4rtr](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/10619/b4rtr).