# Announcing the September–October 2021 topic challenge: Belarusian Literature

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

In accordance with our [meta agreement to have topic challenges](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/571/2191)
and a later [meta agreement to have topic challenges lasting for two months and overlapping by one month](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1175/2191),
it is time to announce the September–October 2021 topic challenge.

Based on the number of votes (+5), the next topic challenge will be

> **Belarusian literature**

---

**What's a topic challenge?**

See the meta posts linked above, and also [this main Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/340816).
In short, during September and October 2021 you are invited to try to get hold of a work of literature in the
[Belarusian language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belarusian_language) and ask questions about it.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, and questions on other works are more than welcome during September and October too;
they just won't count as part of this topic challenge.

**How can I take part?**

By getting hold of a work of literature in the Belarusian language and asking good questions about it.
Questions about these works should be tagged with the author's name, a tag for the work (if it is a book-length publication) and the language tag [belarusian-literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/belarusian-literature).
We'll keep a list of all such questions in an answer to this meta post.

Below is the [presentation](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1533/2191) by [EJoshuaS - Reinstate Monica](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/users/793):

> There have apparently been [recent censorship efforts](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/17848/you-can-enter-prison-for-reading-in-belarus-why) directed at this type of literature, which I think is a good reason to have a reading challenge for it.
>
> More details are available [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belarusian_literature) on this type of literature.
>
> **Edit:** Belarus apparently [just arrested a dissident journalist](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/05/23/world/europe/ryanair-belarus.html?smid=url-share), which seems to make this proposal even more relevant.

**What's next?**

- [Vote for the next topic challenge](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1238/2191) (October–November), or propose your own!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### **List of [all questions posted](https://literature.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bbelarusian-literature%5D+created%3A2021-09-01..2021-10-31+is%3Aquestion) in this topic challenge**

1. [What is Krosyn?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/19437/what-is-krosyn) by [EJoshuaS - Reinstate Monica](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/), 01/09/2021 (5 votes, 1 answer).
2. [What is the significance of the 40-year period referred to in this Francisak Bahusevic poem?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/19461/17) by [EJoshuaS - Reinstate Monica](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/), 04/09/2021 (4 votes, 1 answer).
3. [What was the long list of names in the beginning of "Zinky Boys"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/) by [EJoshuaS - Reinstate Monica](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/), 05/09/2021 (2 votes, 1 answer).
4. [Why did Svetlana Alexievich write "Zinky Boys"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/19477/) by [EJoshuaS - Reinstate Monica](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/), 05/09/2021 (3 votes, 1 answer).
5. [What was the original rhyming scheme of "Do not shun me..."?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/19548/what-was-the-original-rhyming-scheme-of-do-not-shun-me) by [EJoshuaS - Reinstate Monica](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/), 14/09/2021 (2 votes, 1 answer).
6. [Why were Afghanistan veterans treated so poorly relative to World War II veterans?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/19549/) by [EJoshuaS - Reinstate Monica](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/), 15/09/2021 (2 votes, 0 answers).
7. [Why did so many people in Zinky Boys give the temperature as 70 degrees Celsius?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/19552/) by [EJoshuaS - Reinstate Monica](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/), 15/09/2021 (3 votes, 1 answer).
8. [Who wrote this particular poem in Zinky Boys?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/19553/) by [EJoshuaS - Reinstate Monica](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/), 15/09/2021 (3 votes, 0 answers).
9. [What was the first Belarusian novel?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/19588/) by [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/tsundoku), 20.09.2021 (3 votes, 0 answers).
10. [Is Belarus actually hard to farm?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/19688/17) by [EJoshuaS - Reinstate Monica](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/), 02/10/2021 (5 votes, 1 answer).
11. [What does it mean that "your door is stroked with chalk / then at dark a chariot arrives" in Belarus?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/19691/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17), 03.10.2021 (3 votes, 1 answer).
12. [Why the different spellings of Belarus?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/19713/17) by [EJoshuaS - Reinstate Monica](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/), 07/10/2021 (0 votes, 0 answers).
13. [What were Bulgarian biscuits?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/19797/17) by [EJoshuaS - Reinstate Monica](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/), 20/10/2021 (3 votes, 2 answers).
14. [Valzhyna Mort's "it's so hard to believe"](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/19868/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17), 29.10.2021 (1 vote, 0 answers).
15. *add entries in the form `https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>), dd/mm/2021.`*

---

The **highest-voted** of these are [What is Krosyn?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/19437/what-is-krosyn) and [Is Belarus actually hard to farm?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/19688/17), both with a score of **5** at the end of October.

The **most viewed** is [What is Krosyn?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/19437/what-is-krosyn), with approximately **180** views during the months of September and October.