# Best Questions & Answers from 4th Quarter of 2021

Tags: discussion, best-of

Here's the latest installment in the [regular best-of-quarter collections](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-of), intended to gather some particularly good Literature Q&A in order to get some easily available links to showcase our site.

One use for this post could be to gather links for promotion on Literature's [community-run Twitter account](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/689/17). But it's also useful for any kind of site promotion - if we want to show off the site to literary friends, it'll be much easier if we have a list of particularly great posts to point to.

> **Please nominate some exemplary Q&A from the fourth quarter (Oct/Nov/Dec) of 2021**.

(Also, if you find anything from previous months, feel free to go and post answers on any of the older [best-of](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-of) posts linked above. Late entries are more than welcome; the only important date is of the post on the main site that's being nominated.)

- When choosing nominations, please remember the primary purpose: to showcase our site to people elsewhere in the hope of maybe tempting them to come here. Let's try to focus mainly on **great questions with great answers**, and perhaps also **great unanswered questions** (which we can advertise as "hey, why not come and answer this") - *not* anything with subpar answers, which will tend to give a bad impression and defeat the purpose.
- Remember that **votes don't necessarily reflect quality**, and the purpose of this is to promote quality over score. Highly-voted posts are easy to find, underappreciated gems less so.
- Getting a wide range of different stories represented in our list here would also be nice, but not strictly necessary - feel free to nominate a bunch of Q&A about the same book, if you think they're all outstanding. But don't nominate questions just because they're about your favourite book.
- Multiple nominated posts per answer here is fine.
- Feel free to nominate either some of your own posts which you're particularly proud of, or posts from other people which really impressed you.
- Ideally, some explanation of *why* the nominated questions and answers are so good would be useful - constructive feedback might give people ideas about what to aim for in the future.

Comment: Useful queries: [answered questions (138)](https://literature.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3A2021-10..2021-12+is%3Aquestion+isanswered%3Ayes), [unanswered questions (94)](https://literature.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3A2021-10..2021-12+is%3Aquestion+isanswered%3Ano), [answers (245)](https://literature.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3A2021-10..2021-12+is%3Aanswer).

Answer (score 3):

I really enjoyed (and learned a lot from) answering [How long has Kalevipoeg been considered the Estonian national epic?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/20214/17) This question is a lot more interesting than it may seem: the answer is not just a simple matter of hunting down and dating references in the literature, but requires some investigation of **what it *means* to be a "national epic"**, which is more of a cultural question than a literary one, but very important in getting to grips with the reception (and even, as it turns out, the *creation*) of certain works of literature. Constructing that answer was a fascinating and educational experience for me. There are also similar questions (all asked by Tsundoku during December) about other cultures' national epics: [Iranian](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/20168/17), [Thai](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/20183/17), [Armenian](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/20186/17), [Spanish](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/20202/17), [Georgian](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/20254/17) (deleted), [Kyrgyz](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/20289/17), [Meitei](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/20306/17). Don't upvote them all at once, as the system will think it's serial voting, but they're probably all worth upvoting.

It was also pleasing to see the [Decameron topic challenge](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1607/17) (November-December) attract [Charo](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/10143/charo), already well established on the SE network with a moderator diamond on Italian SE, to start posting more actively here, answering six of my Decameron questions during the 4th quarter of 2021. If I had to pick a favourite answer of Charo's (among those posted so far, hopefully more to come!), it would be [What do the names of the Decameron characters signify?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/19914/17) which I rewarded with a bounty.

Answer (score 1):

HoldOffHunger's [answer to the question "Did Thoreau respond to claims that he was an anarchist?"](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/20094/2191) addresses each sub-question in the original question and is well-documented. (HoldOffHunger joined the site in the fourth quarter of 2021. The question itself dates from the first quarter.)