# Announcing the July–August 2022 topic challenge: Ukrainian Literature

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

In accordance with our [meta agreement to have topic challenges](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/571/2191)
and a later [meta agreement to have topic challenges lasting for two months and overlapping by one month](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1175/2191),
it is time to announce the July–August 2022 topic challenge.

Based on the number of votes (+5), the next topic challenge of the year 2022 will be
**Ukrainian Literature**.

---

**What's a topic challenge?**

See the meta posts linked above, and also [this main Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/340816).
In short, during July and August 2022 you are invited to try to read at least one work of Ukrainian literature and ask questions about it.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, and questions on other works are more than welcome during July and August too;
they just won't count as part of this topic challenge.

**How can I take part?**

By getting hold of the one or more works of Ukrainian literature and asking good questions about it (or them).
Questions about these works should be tagged with the name of the author, the name of the work (for book-length works) and either [ukrainian-literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ukrainian-literature) or [russian-literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/russian-literature), depending on the language of the work.
We'll keep a list of all such questions in an answer to this meta post.

Below is the [presentation](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1672/2191) originally posted by [EJoshuaS - Stand with Ukraine](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/) with edits from other users:

> In protest of the recent vicious assault on their country.
>
> Scope would be authors who self-identify as Ukrainian (even if writing in a different language), and authors writing in Ukrainian.
>
> Below are a few Ukrainian authors whose works are at least partially available in English:
>
> - [Oksana Zabuzhko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oksana_Zabuzhko), e.g. *Field Work In Ukrainian Sex* (1996, controversial but influential),
> - [Ihor Pavlyuk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ihor_Pavlyuk), e.g. *A Flight over the Black Sea* (2014),
> - [Serhiy Zhadan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serhiy_Zhadan), e.g. [*Voroshilovgrad*](https://store.deepvellum.org/products/voroshilovgrad), [*Depeche Mode*](https://glagoslav.com/shop/depeche-mode-by-serhiy-zhadan/) and [poetry in English translations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serhiy_Zhadan#Poetry_in_English_translations),
> - [Markiyan Kamysh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markiyan_Kamysh), who represents the Chernobyl underground in literature,
> - [Yuri Andrukhovych](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yurii_Andrukhovych), e.g. [*The Moscoviad*](http://www.spuytenduyvil.net/moscoviad.html),
> - [Yuriy Vynnychuk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuriy_Vynnychuk): [*Tango of Death*](http://www.spuytenduyvil.net/tango-of-death.html).

**Update 27.06.2022**: [Serhiy Zhadan awarded 2022 Peace Prize of the German Book Trade](https://www.dw.com/en/ukrainian-serhiy-zhadan-wins-german-peace-prize/a-62274648).

**What's next?**

- [Vote for the next topic challenge](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1238/2191), or propose your own!

Comment: recently "Daughter" by Tamara Duda was published in English

Answer (score 5):

**List of all questions posted in this topic challenge**

1. [What is a "more bankable nationality"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/22751/what-is-a-more-bankable-nationality) by [EJoshuaS - Stand with Ukraine](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/ejoshuas-stand-with-ukraine) on 01/07/2022
2. [Was pigskin leather easier to acquire in the Ukrainian Soviet Socialist Republic than cattle leather?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/22765/was-pigskin-leather-easier-to-acquire-in-the-ukrainian-soviet-socialist-republic)  by [EJoshuaS - Stand with Ukraine](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/ejoshuas-stand-with-ukraine) on 02.07.2022
3. [Did Effie receive insulin shock therapy?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/22786/did-effie-receive-insulin-shock-therapy) by [EJoshuaS - Stand with Ukraine](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/ejoshuas-stand-with-ukraine) on 03.07.2022
4. [When did the Soviet government start admitting that people were killed in Afghanistan?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/22785/when-did-the-soviet-government-start-admitting-that-people-were-killed-in-afghan) by [EJoshuaS - Stand with Ukraine](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/ejoshuas-stand-with-ukraine) on 03.07.2022
5. [Was a pumpkin a symbol of rejection of a suitor?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/22831/was-a-pumpkin-a-symbol-of-rejection-of-a-suitor) by [EJoshuaS - Stand with Ukraine](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/ejoshuas-stand-with-ukraine) on 11.07.2022
6. [Do academic historians regard the fact that the USSR was exporting food during the Holodomor as evidence that it was intentional?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/22833/do-academic-historians-regard-the-fact-that-the-ussr-was-exporting-food-during-t) by [EJoshuaS - Stand with Ukraine](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/ejoshuas-stand-with-ukraine) on 11.07.2022
7. [What is an Akhmatovian nose?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/22872/what-is-an-akhmatovian-nose) by [EJoshuaS - Stand with Ukraine](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/ejoshuas-stand-with-ukraine) on 19.07.2022
8. [Was Milena's husband evading taxes?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/22897/was-milenas-husband-evading-taxes) by [EJoshuaS - Stand with Ukraine](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/ejoshuas-stand-with-ukraine) on 25.07.2022
9. [Why are Santa Barbara, Denver, and Dallas held up as examples of the glamorous high life?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/22896/why-are-santa-barbara-denver-and-dallas-held-up-as-examples-of-the-glamorous-h) by [EJoshuaS - Stand with Ukraine](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/ejoshuas-stand-with-ukraine) on 25.07.2022
10. [Why does "Your Ad Could Go Here" state that the Orange Revolution lasted for three weeks?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/22924/why-does-your-ad-could-go-here-state-that-the-orange-revolution-lasted-for-thr) by [EJoshuaS - Stand with Ukraine](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/ejoshuas-stand-with-ukraine) on 02.08.2022
11. [Is "An Album for Gustav" referring to the author's language skills?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/22923/which-languages-does-oksana-zabuzhko-know-well) by [EJoshuaS - Stand with Ukraine](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/ejoshuas-stand-with-ukraine) on 02.08.2022
12. [Why would a government official boast to a reporter about illegal trips to Chernobyl?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/22937/why-would-a-government-official-boast-to-a-reporter-about-illegal-trips-to-chern) by [EJoshuaS - Stand with Ukraine](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/ejoshuas-stand-with-ukraine) on 04.08.2022
13. [What is a State Duma Deputy?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/22936/what-is-a-state-duma-deputy) by [EJoshuaS - Stand with Ukraine](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/ejoshuas-stand-with-ukraine) on 04.08.2022
14. [Was "Fyodor in Crime" a reference to Dostoevsky?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/22941/was-fyodor-in-crime-a-reference-to-dostoevsky) by [EJoshuaS - Stand with Ukraine](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/ejoshuas-stand-with-ukraine) on 06.08.2022
15. [What is a District Militiaman?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/22951/what-is-a-district-militiaman) by [EJoshuaS - Stand with Ukraine](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/ejoshuas-stand-with-ukraine) on 08.08.2022
16. [Were mines common in Ukraine?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/23010/were-mines-common-in-ukraine) by [EJoshuaS - Stand with Ukraine](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/ejoshuas-stand-with-ukraine) on 18.08.2022
17. [Why did Misha give Viktor and Sonya New Year's gifts?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/23009/why-did-misha-give-viktor-and-sonya-new-years-gifts) by [EJoshuaS - Stand with Ukraine](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/ejoshuas-stand-with-ukraine) on 18.08.2022
18. [Why did the Chief stop in Cyprus on his way to Rome?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/23044/why-did-the-chief-stop-in-cyprus-on-his-way-to-rome) by [EJoshuaS - Stand with Ukraine](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/ejoshuas-stand-with-ukraine) on 22.08.2022
19. [Did it really cost $800 to fly from Kyiv to Rome in 1999?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/23043/did-it-really-cost-800-to-fly-from-kyiv-to-rome-in-1999) by [EJoshuaS - Stand with Ukraine](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/ejoshuas-stand-with-ukraine) on 22.08.2022
20. [Why does Wikipedia claim that "Death and the Penguin" was set in 1996 - 1997?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/23061/why-does-wikipedia-claim-that-death-and-the-penguin-was-set-in-1996-1997) by [EJoshuaS - Stand with Ukraine](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/ejoshuas-stand-with-ukraine) on 23.08.2022
21. [Is the "wall of solitude" a reference to Pink Floyd's "The Wall"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/23060/is-the-wall-of-solitude-a-reference-to-pink-floyds-the-wall) by [EJoshuaS - Stand with Ukraine](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/ejoshuas-stand-with-ukraine) on 23.08.2022
22. [Why does "Like Harps, Like Harps" end with "Lament..."?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/23081/why-does-like-harps-like-harps-end-with-lament) by [EJoshuaS - Stand with Ukraine](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/ejoshuas-stand-with-ukraine) on 27.08.2022
23. [Why did Pavlo Tychyna have to reject his Nobel Prize nomination?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/23080/why-did-pavlo-tychynia-have-to-reject-his-nobel-prize-nomination) by [EJoshuaS - Stand with Ukraine](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/ejoshuas-stand-with-ukraine) on 27.08.2022
24. [Why was the rye angry about being called "golden"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/23082/why-was-the-rye-angry-about-being-called-golden) by [EJoshuaS - Stand with Ukraine](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/ejoshuas-stand-with-ukraine) on 27.08.2022
25. *add entries in the form `https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>), dd/mm/2022.`*

---

The **highest-voted** of these are
[Was a pumpkin a symbol of rejection of a suitor?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/22831/was-a-pumpkin-a-symbol-of-rejection-of-a-suitor) and [Why are Santa Barbara, Denver, and Dallas held up as examples of the glamorous high life?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/22896/why-are-santa-barbara-denver-and-dallas-held-up-as-examples-of-the-glamorous-h)
with a score of 7 at the end of August.

The **most viewed** is [Why are Santa Barbara, Denver, and Dallas held up as examples of the glamorous high life?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/22896/why-are-santa-barbara-denver-and-dallas-held-up-as-examples-of-the-glamorous-h), with approximately 4000 views during the months of July and August.