# Announcing the October–November 2023 topic challenge: Bibhutibhushan Bandyopadhyay

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

In accordance with our [meta agreement to have topic challenges](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/571/)
and a later [meta agreement to have topic challenges lasting for two months and overlapping by one month](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1175/),
it is (long past) time to announce the October–November 2023 topic challenge.

Based on the number of votes (+6/-0), the next topic challenge of the year 2023 will be:

> ### Bibhutibhushan Bandyopadhyay

---

**What's a topic challenge?**

See the meta posts linked above, and also [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/). In short, during October and November 2023 you are invited to try to read at least one Bibhutibhushan Bandyopadhyay story and ask questions about it.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, and questions on other works are more than welcome during October and November too; they just won't count as part of this topic challenge.

**How can I take part?**

By getting hold of some works of Bibhutibhushan Bandyopadhyay and asking (or answering!) good questions about them. Questions about these works should be tagged with [bibhutibhushan-bandyopadhyay](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bibhutibhushan-bandyopadhyay) and other tags as appropriate. We'll keep a list of all such questions in an answer to this meta post.

Below is the
[presentation](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1459/17) (written by Tsundoku although the original suggestion was from user37920):

> [Bibhutibhushan Bandyopadhyay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bibhutibhushan_Bandyopadhyay) (1894 – 1950) was an author from West Bengal in India and his works are mostly set in rural Bengal. According to the British poet and critic Martin Seymour-Smith, author of *Guide to Modern World Literature* (1973), Bandyopadhyay was "perhaps the best of all modern Indian novelists", adding that "probably nothing in twentieth-century Indian literature, in prose or poetry, comes to the level of *Pather Panchali*".
>
> His works include the following:
>
> - *Pather Panchali*, an autobiographical novel published in 1929, which brought him to prominence,
> - *Chander Pahar*, "one of the most-loved adventure novels in the Bengali literature" ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chander_Pahar)), published in 1937,
> - *Aranyak* (literally "Of the Forest"), a novel that "explores the journey of the protagonist Satyacharan in the dichotomy of the urban and jungle lives" ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aranyak)).

**What's next?**

- [Vote for the next topic challenge](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1238/) (November–December), or propose your own topic!

Answer (score 0):

### **List of [all questions posted](https://literature.stackexchange.com/search?q=%bibhutibhushan-bandyopadhyay%5D+created%3A2023-10-01..2023-11-30+is%3Aquestion) in this topic challenge**

No [bibhutibhushan-bandyopadhyay](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bibhutibhushan-bandyopadhyay) questions were posted during this topic challenge.