# Announcing the March – April 2024 topic challenge: Uyghur literature

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

In accordance with our [meta agreement to have topic challenges](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/571/)
and a later [meta agreement to have topic challenges lasting for two months and overlapping by one month](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1175/),
it is (actually past) time to announce the March – April 2024 topic challenge.

Based on the number of votes (+5/-1), the third topic challenge fully in 2024 will be:

> ### Uyghur literature

---

**What's a topic challenge?**

See the meta posts linked above, and also [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/). In short, during March and April 2024 you are invited to try to read at least one work that was originally written in the [Uyghur language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uyghur_language) and ask questions about it.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, and questions on other works are more than welcome during March and April too; they just won't count as part of this topic challenge.

**How can I take part?**

By getting hold of some works of Uyghur literature and asking (or answering!) good questions about them. Questions about these works should be tagged with [uyghur-language](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uyghur-language) and an author tag and other tags as appropriate. We'll keep a list of all such questions in an answer to this meta post.

EJoshuaS's
[presentation](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1659/17) of the topic included [this link](https://uyghurcollective.com/community/f/uyghur-literature-in-translation-english) to a list of Uyghur literature that's been translated to English.

**What's next?**

- [Vote for the next topic challenge](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1238/17) (April–May), or propose your own topic!
- Feel free to edit links into this post if you find some good resources on Uyghur literature.

Answer (score 1):

### **List of [all questions posted](https://literature.stackexchange.com/search?q=%uyghur-language%5D+created%3A2024-03-01..2024-04-30+is%3Aquestion) in this topic challenge**

1. [What is the significance of the drawings in the first few pages of "Drops of Melodies"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/26355/what-is-the-significance-of-the-drawings-in-the-first-few-pages-of-drops-of-mel) by [EJoshuaS - Stand with Ukraine](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/ejoshuas-stand-with-ukraine), 01/03/2024.
2. [Why are children described as "folly free" in the poem "Mothers Heart"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/26356/why-are-children-described-as-folly-free-in-the-poem-mothers-heart) by [EJoshuaS - Stand with Ukraine](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/ejoshuas-stand-with-ukraine), 01/03/2024.
3. [What does it mean for a "bad eye" to "touch" something?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/26439/what-does-it-mean-for-a-bad-eye-to-touch-something) by [EJoshuaS - Stand with Ukraine](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/ejoshuas-stand-with-ukraine), 16/03/2024
4. [Why doesn't the person that the narrator is waiting for show up in this poem by Hemurah Tohti?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/26456/why-doesnt-the-person-that-the-narrator-is-waiting-for-show-up-in-this-poem-by) by [EJoshuaS - Stand with Ukraine](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/ejoshuas-stand-with-ukraine), 16/03/2024
5. *add entries in the form `https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>), dd/mm/2024.`*

---

The **highest-voted** of these is *[question URL]*, with a score of *TBD* at the end of April.

The **most viewed** is *[question URL]*, with approximately *TBD* views by the end of April.

*TBD* questions received at least one answer.

---

Reviews submitted to our Tumblr blog: *TBD*.