# Announcing the June 2017 topic challenge: The SEA is Ours

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

In accordance with our meta agreement to have [topic challenges](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/571/11), seeing that the votes have [stabilised](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/649/timeline), May is nearing its end, and it's time to announce the next topic challenge! Throughout **June 2017**, our topic challenge, [proposed](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/618/481) by [BESW](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/users/151/besw), will be

> ### Topic challenge: *The SEA is Ours*
>
> *The SEA is Ours* is a 2015 anthology of steampunk stories by and about Southeast Asians. While collected with a Western audience in
>   mind, its goal is to challenge the assumptions of a genre with a
>   traditionally colonial, Anglo-centric focus, and showcase how its
>   aesthetic and themes can transcend that narrow origin.
>
> Questions would range from cultural context research to examining how
>   the steampunk ethos is re-imagined through cultural epistemologies
>   outside the Euro-American experience. Critical comparisons to
>   so-called silkpunk seem inevitable.

As with the previous announcements, I post this before the actual start of the challenge, so that everyone has time to prepare. The topic challenge will start on June 1st.

---

**What is a topic challenge?**

During a topic challenge, community members read and ask questions about a particular topic.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, but those who participate will be forever remembered in the [annals](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/739/481) of our history.

Question on other topics are always welcome as well, but they won't count as a part of this challenge.

**How does one participate?**

To participate in this topic challenge, all one has to do is ask or answer a question related to *The SEA is Ours* during June 2017. That simple! Questions asked in the scope of this topic challenge should be tagged with [short-stories](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-stories) and the appropriate author tag.

You can check if a local library has a copy of the book via WorldCat either [here](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/952457016) or [here](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/951964024). ([h/t Hamlet](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37710275#37710275))

**What else?**

- Vote [here](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/596/11) for the next topic challenge, or propose your own!

Comment: Discussion about anthology tags can be found [here](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/740/481).

Comment: Bleh. Those WorldCat links only list a single copy in the whole of the UK, in SOAS.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Buying it doesn't seem much easier. I ordered it at the beginning of the month, but I'm not too confident it'll arrive before the end of the month.

Comment: Should have complained earlier, just got the shipping notification...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### **List of all questions asked as a part of this challenge:**

- [Were the contributors to "The SEA is Ours" all already established authors?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/2795/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17/rand-althor)
- [Do the stories in "The SEA is Ours" accurately portray the essential aspects of South-East Asian culture?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/2797/17) by [Shokhet](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/481/shokhet)
- *far too few* **:-(**

---

The **highest-voted** of these is [Were the contributors to "The SEA is Ours" all already established authors?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/2795/17), with a score of **6** at the end of the month.

The **most viewed** is [Do the stories in "The SEA is Ours" accurately portray the essential aspects of South-East Asian culture?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/2797/17), with approximately **27** views during the month.

Only the first question received an answer.

Comment: This may not be perfect, but [this search](https://literature.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22the+sea+is+ours%22+is%3Aq+created%3A2017-06) should find most of the questions asked for this month's challenge.