# Do we want anthology tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

Our next topic challenge will be the anthology *The SEA is Ours*. It's an anthology, meaning it's a collection of short stories.

Should we have a *The SEA is Ours* tag?

Comment: Credit to Shokhet for pointing this out

Answer (score 5):

I don't see how a tag for an anthology makes sense for questions that are about texts that are collected in this anthology. An anthology mostly collects texts that were not written *for* this anthology, so tagging a question about a particular short story with one particular anthology that happens to contain it makes no sense.

(I also think that a tag for a collection of stories, where the stories were written for the collection, is too specific, but that's [another story](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362/should-we-be-tagging-questions-with-the-names-of-specific-books).)

A tag for an anthology could make sense if the question is about the choice of stories that make up this anthology, or about how this anthology was a source of inspiration, but these are really rare cases.

Comment: What tags should be used for a question asking us to identify an anthology? Like this one for example: https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/9617/anthology-one-story-about-an-astronaut-falling-on-flowers-another-about-a-wife

Comment: @user14111 That's one of those rare cases where [tag:anthology] would make sense, but even so it isn't very useful. Who is an expert in _anthologies_ specifically (as opposed to stories that were never published in an anthology)? Is it really useful to search for `[story-identification] [anthology] …` as opposed to `[story-identification] anthology …`?