# Should we tag song lyrics questions by composer or artist?

Tags: discussion, tags

We've got a substantial amount of [song-lyrics](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/song-lyrics) questions. So far, a lot of them are tagged with the artist (e.g. [rolling-stones](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rolling-stones), [radiohead](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radiohead)), and a few with the composer (e.g. [leonard-cohen](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leonard-cohen)).

It's probably better to be consistent, in addition that both options have pros and cons that should probably be discussed.

Should we be tagging by artist or composer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should we tag questions about song lyrics?](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/852/how-should-we-tag-questions-about-song-lyrics)