# Announcing the August 2017 Topic Challenge: “Sophie's World”

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

In accordance with our [meta agreement](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/571/17) to have topic challenges, and since the [list of suggestions](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/596/17) has a single highest-voted entry as July nears its end, it's time to announce the next topic challenge! Throughout **August 2017**, our topic challenge, [proposed](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/623/17) by [Mithrandir](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/58/mithrandir), will be

> ### **[*Sophie's World*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie%27s_World), by Jostein Gaarder**.

As with the previous announcements, I'm posting this before the actual start of the challenge, so that people have time to prepare, get a copy of the book to start reading, and so forth. The topic challenge itself will start on the 1st of August.

---

**What's a topic challenge?**

See the meta posts linked above, and also [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/278659). In short, during August we should all read *Sophie's World* and try to post thoughtful and interesting questions about it.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, but those who participate will be forever remembered in the [annals](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/810/17) of our history. And of course it goes without saying that questions on other works are more than welcome during August too; they just won't count as part of this topic challenge.

**How can I take part?**

By getting hold of the book, in whatever language you prefer, and asking good questions about it. (It's been translated into English and many other languages, but it's not old enough to be out of copyright.) These questions should be tagged with [sophies-world](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sophies-world) and [jostein-gaarder](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jostein-gaarder) and [scandinavian-literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scandinavian-literature), and other tags if applicable. We'll keep a list of all such questions in an answer to this meta post.

**What's next?**

- Vote [here](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/596/17) for the next topic challenge, or propose your own!

Comment: I don't see this as a particularly good topic challenge. I can think of many more interesting and more culturally relevant books that also discuss philosophy. And aside from the fact that we haven't had any questions about this particular book, this book is similar to a lot of other books on this site. For example, we have plenty of questions about pop philosophy books, such as The Zen and Art of Motorcycle Maintenance. We also have plenty of questions about European authors. I don't see this question increasing the diversity of this site in any significant way.

Comment: @Hamlet *shrug* It was the highest-voted suggestion on the topic challenge proposals thread. Maybe you should have made your criticism of this suggestion earlier, so that more people would have seen it before upvoting. Anyway, let's hope we get some interesting questions about this book, even if it is a bit too European.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**List of [all questions posted](https://literature.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=[sophies-world]%20created%3a2017-08-01..2017-08-31%20is%3aquestion) as part of the August 2017 Topic Challenge**

- [Why is it important that 'Nowadays it's the girl who takes the initiative'?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/3189/58) by [Mithrandir](https://literature.stackexchange.com/u/58)
- [When did Sophie and Alberto become real?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/3217/when-did-sophie-and-alberto-become-real) by [Mithrandir](https://literature.stackexchange.com/u/58)
- [What is Sophie saying about the Tower of Babel here?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/3229/what-is-sophie-saying-about-the-tower-of-babel-here) by [Mithrandir](https://literature.stackexchange.com/u/58)
- [How does it improve the book to show the major's power?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/3258/how-does-it-improve-the-book-to-show-the-majors-power) by [heather](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/1982/heather)
- *add entries in the form `https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)`*

---

The **highest-voted** of these is [Why is it important that 'Nowadays it's the girl who takes the initiative'?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/3189/why-is-it-important-that-nowadays-its-the-girl-who-takes-the-initiative), with a score of 6 at the end of the month.

The **most viewed** is [Why is it important that 'Nowadays it's the girl who takes the initiative'?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/3189/why-is-it-important-that-nowadays-its-the-girl-who-takes-the-initiative), with approximately 56 views during the month.

**Two answers** were submitted during the topic challenge.