# Announcing the September 2017 Topic Challenge: Persepolis by Marjane Satrapi

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

In accordance with our [meta agreement](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/571/17) to have topic challenges, and since the [list of suggestions](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/596/17) has a single highest-voted entry as August nears its end, it's time to announce the next topic challenge! Throughout **September 2017**, our topic challenge, [proposed](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/787/111) by  Torisuda, will be

> ### ***Persepolis* by Marjane Satrapi**.

As with the previous announcements, I'm posting this before the actual start of the challenge, so that people have time to prepare, get a copy of the book to start reading, and so forth. The topic challenge itself will start on the 1st of September.

### The topic challenge has begun - ask your *Persepolis* questions now!

---

**What's a topic challenge?**

See the meta posts linked above, and also [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/278659). In short, during September we should all read *Persepolis* and try to post thoughtful and interesting questions about it.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, but those who participate will be forever remembered in the [annals](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/863/17) of our history. And of course it goes without saying that questions on other works are more than welcome during September too; they just won't count as part of this topic challenge.

**How can I take part?**

By getting hold of the book, in whatever language you prefer, and asking good questions about it. (It's been translated into English and many other languages, but it's not old enough to be out of copyright.) These questions should be tagged with [persepolis](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/persepolis) and [marjane-satrapi](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marjane-satrapi) and [french-literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/french-literature), and other tags if applicable. We'll keep a list of all such questions in an answer to this meta post.

**What's next?**

- Vote [here](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/596/17) for the next topic challenge, or propose your own!

Comment: Well, that was a dismal failure :'(

Comment: Don't forget to accept the CW answer below ...

Answer (score 3):

**List of [all questions posted](https://literature.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=[persepolis]%20created%3a2017-09-01..2017-09-30%20is%3aquestion) as part of the September 2017 Topic Challenge**

- [In which countries has Persepolis been banned?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/3687/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17)

---

It had a score of **-1** at the end of the month, and approximately **10** views during the month. And no answers.

`:-/`