# Announcing the October 2017 Topic Challenge: "A Grain of Wheat", by Ngũgĩ wa Thiong'o

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

In accordance with our [meta agreement](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/571/58) to have topic challenges, and since the [list of suggestions](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/596/58) has a single highest-voted entry as September nears its end, it's time to announce the next topic challenge! Throughout **October 2017**, our topic challenge, [proposed](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/777/58) by  Hamlet, will be

> ### ***A Grain of Wheat* by Ngũgĩ wa Thiong'o**.

As with the previous announcements, I'm posting this before the actual start of the challenge, so that people have time to prepare, get a copy of the book to start reading, and so forth. The topic challenge itself will start on the 1st of October.

---

**What's a topic challenge?**

See the meta posts linked above, and also [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/). In short, during October we should all read *A Grain of Wheat* and try to post thoughtful and interesting questions about it.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, but those who participate will be forever remembered in the [annals](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/892/58) of our history. And of course it goes without saying that questions on other works are more than welcome during October too; they just won't count as part of this topic challenge.

**How can I take part?**

By getting hold of the book, in whatever language you prefer, and asking good questions about it. These questions should be tagged with [a-grain-of-wheat](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-grain-of-wheat), [ngugi-wa-thiongo](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ngugi-wa-thiongo), and other tags if applicable. We'll keep a list of all such questions in an answer to this meta post.

**What's next?**

- Vote [here](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/596/58) for the next topic challenge, or propose your own!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**List of [all questions posted](https://literature.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=[a-grain-of-wheat]%20created%3a2017-10-01..2017-10-31%20is%3aquestion) as part of the October 2017 Topic Challenge:**

- [Before reading "A Grain of Wheat," what historical facts and cultural context are useful to know?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/3924/17) by [Zyera](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/80/zyera)
- [Meanings of the Kenyan dialect words used in "A Grain of Wheat"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/3967/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17/rand-althor)
- *add entries in the form `https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)`*

---

The **highest-voted** of these is [Before reading "A Grain of Wheat," what historical facts and cultural context are useful to know?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/3924/17), with a score of **5** at the end of the month.

The **most viewed** is [Before reading "A Grain of Wheat," what historical facts and cultural context are useful to know?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/3924/17), with approximately **60** views during the month.

Only the second question received an answer.