# Announcing the November 2017 reading challenge: "Tower of Secrets"

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

As October nears its end, it's time to announce the next month's challenge! At the time of writing this, the leading suggestion is...

### *Tower of Secrets*, by Victor Sheymov, [suggested by BESW](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/620).

To provide their motivation for suggesting this book:

> Tower of Secrets by Victor Sheymov is an autobiographical account of a KGB agent's gradual disillusionment with communism and his eventual defection. It's entertaining simply as a spy thriller, and insightful as a historical document, but Tower is also notable for the storytelling techniques Sheymov uses to help Western readers enter the perspective and mindspace of a KGB operative.

---

Our reading challenge tradition comes from [here](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/571/do-we-want-something-akin-to-topic-challenges-for-books-outside-our-bailiwick-t). In short, during November, any question asked about *Tower of Secrets* (and tagged with [tower-of-secrets](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tower-of-secrets), [victor-sheymov](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/victor-sheymov), and [russian-literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/russian-literature)) will be considered part of the challenge - [go for it!](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

---

As usual, we always welcome new challenge ideas in [this post](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/596/suggest-your-lit-se-reading-challenges-here).

Comment: Sorry for late entries. It took a while to find free time to read the book.

Comment: @DVK what happened to your second question?

Comment: @Gallifreyan - no idea. Mod-deleted? It was about the "third person"

Comment: @DVK, Gall: It's [still up](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/4533/17), but I retagged it because it seems to be more about terminology than about *Tower of Secrets* itself as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**List of [all questions posted](https://literature.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=[tower-of-secrets]%20created%3a2017-11-01..2017-11-30%20is%3aquestion) as part of the November 2017 Topic Challenge:**

- [How did Sheymov manage to convince KGB that he and the family were dead?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/4532/how-did-sheymov-manage-to-convince-kgb-that-he-and-the-family-were-dead) by [DVK](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/31/dvk)

---

It had a score of **3** at the end of the month, with approximately **10** views during the month. No answers were submitted.

`:-/`

Comment: is this available online, for free, anywhere?

Comment: @Vekzhivi - [not from a *Jedi*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iKF0julgLJ4).