# Announcing the February 2018 Topic Challenge: “Songs of Innocence and of Experience”

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

After a brief hiatus over the Christmas and New Year period (because apparently virtual hats and topic challenges are too much fun to have all at the same time), **Lit.SE topic challenges are back!**

---

In accordance with our [meta agreement](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/571/17) to have topic challenges, and since the [list of suggestions](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/596/17) has a single highest-voted entry as January nears its end, it's time to announce the next topic challenge! Throughout **February 2018**, our topic challenge, [proposed](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/599/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17/rand-althor), will be

> ### **[*Songs of Innocence and of Experience*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Songs_of_Innocence_and_of_Experience), by William Blake**.

As with the previous announcements, I'm posting this before the actual start of the challenge, so that people have time to see this meta, read the poems, prepare their questions, and so forth. The topic challenge itself will start on the 1st of February.

---

**What's a topic challenge?**

See the meta posts linked above, and also [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/278659). In short, during February we should all try to read (at least some of) Blake's Songs of Innocence and of Experience, and to post thoughtful and interesting questions about them.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, but those who participate will be forever remembered in the [annals](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/996/17) of our history. And of course it goes without saying that questions on other works are more than welcome during February too; they just won't count as part of this topic challenge.

**How can I take part?**

By getting hold of the poems, in whatever language you prefer, and asking good questions about them. (The collection is out of copyright and [available in full at Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/1934/1934-h/1934-h.htm).) These questions should be tagged with [william-blake](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/william-blake) and [poetry](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry) and either [songs-of-innocence](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/songs-of-innocence) or [songs-of-experience](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/songs-of-experience), and other tags if applicable. We'll keep a list of all such questions in an answer to this meta post.

**What's next?**

- Vote [here](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/596/17) for the next topic challenge, or propose your own!

Comment: @Mithrandir please make this [tag:featured]!

Comment: @muru - Instead of featuring it, I created a Community Event, which also shows up on the sidebar.

Comment: Can my [question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/5307/why-are-the-u2-cds-named-after-songs-of-innocence-and-songs-of-experience-by) about how the U2 CDs of the same name relate to the poems be included, even though it was posted in January?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **List of [all questions posted](https://literature.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsongs-of-innocence%5D+or+%5Bsongs-of-experience%5D+created%3A2018-02-01..2018-02-28+is%3Aquestion) as part of the February 2018 Topic Challenge**

- [Why weren't Blake's poems published in their original painted form?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/5579/17) by [No one text](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2988/no-one-text)
- [What does "chartered" mean in Blake's poem "London"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/5582/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17/rand-althor)
- [Are Songs of Experience and Songs of Innocence actually songs? Or is the word song a metaphor?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/5583/17) by [Musical Poetry](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2992/musical-poetry)
- [Bright or brightly?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/5585/17) by [Musical Poetry](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2993/musical-poetry)
- [Why is "The Chimney Sweeper" in Songs of Innocence rather than Songs of Experience?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/5596/why-is-the-chimney-sweeper-in-songs-of-innocence) by [EJoshuaS](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/ejoshuas)
- [What are the "mind-forged manacles"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/5604/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17/rand-althor)
- [What is the meaning of Blake's poem "The Sick Rose"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/5728/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17/rand-althor)
- [Why is the robin "sobbing"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/5811/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17/rand-althor)
- https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/5817/how-did-songs-of-innocence-and-experience-inspire-airbag-by-radiohead by [EJoshuaS](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/ejoshuas)
- [Is the comparison in "The Clod and the Pebble" between different types of love?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/5829) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17/rand-althor)
- *add entries in the form `https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)`*

---

The **highest-voted** of these are [Are Songs of Experience and Songs of Innocence actually songs? Or is the word song a metaphor?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/5583/17) and [Why is "The Chimney Sweeper" in Songs of Innocence rather than Songs of Experience?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/5596/17), both with a score of **6** at the end of the month.

The **most viewed** is [Why is "The Chimney Sweeper" in Songs of Innocence rather than Songs of Experience?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/5596/17), with approximately **150** views during the month.

**Nine answers** were submitted during the topic challenge.