# Announcing the March 2018 Topic Challenge: the works of Michael Ende

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

Two days late (sorry), here's the next Literature SE topic challenge: our first author-based challenge!

---

In accordance with our [meta agreement](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/571/17) to have topic challenges, and since the [list of suggestions](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/596/17) has a single highest-voted entry at the end of February, it's time to announce the next topic challenge. Throughout **March 2018**, our topic challenge, [proposed](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/742/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17/rand-althor), will be

> ### **the works of [Michael Ende](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Ende)**.

---

**What's a topic challenge?**

See the meta posts linked above, and also [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/278659). In short, during March we should all try to read something by Michael Ende, and to post thoughtful and interesting questions about it.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, but those who participate will be forever remembered in the [annals](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1010/17) of our history. And of course it goes without saying that questions on other works are more than welcome during March too; they just won't count as part of this topic challenge.

**How can I take part?**

By getting hold of Michael Ende stories, in whatever language you prefer, and asking good questions about them. These questions should be tagged with [michael-ende](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/michael-ende), and [german-literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/german-literature) if originally written in German, and specific-work tags such as [momo](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/momo) or [the-neverending-story](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-neverending-story) etc. if applicable. We'll keep a list of all such questions in an answer to this meta post.

**What's next?**

- Vote [here](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/596/17) for the next topic challenge, or propose your own!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **List of [all questions posted](https://literature.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmichael-ende%5D+created%3A2018-03-01..2018-03-31+is%3Aquestion) as part of the March 2018 Topic Challenge**

- [Where is Momo set?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/5917/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17/rand-althor)
- [What methods have been used to distinguish the text between the two strands of The Neverending Story?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/5932/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17/rand-althor)
- [Predecessors/Inspirations of Scheinriesen (Illusionary Giants)](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/5943/predecessors-inspirations-of-scheinriesen-illusionary-giants) by [Narusan](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/1929/narusan)
- [In the "Neverending Story", what judgement do Falkor and Atreyu make of the Childlike Empress?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/5973/in-the-neverending-story-what-judgement-do-falkor-and-atreyu-make-of-the-chil) by [Chris Sunami](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/101/chris-sunami)
- [What are all the stories left unfinished in The Neverending Story?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/6055/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17/rand-althor)
- [Does the title of "The Neverending Story" have a double meaning?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/6102/does-the-title-of-the-neverending-story-have-a-double-meaning) by [EJoshuaS](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/ejoshuas)
- [Why do the names of the first two characters introduced in "The Neverending Story" start with B and C?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/6103/why-do-the-names-of-the-first-two-characters-introduced-in-the-neverending-stor) by [EJoshuaS](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/ejoshuas)
- [Is it possible that Bastian's journey to Fantastica was purely metaphysical?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/6154/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17/rand-althor)
- [Why "Moon Child"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/6173/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17/rand-althor)
- [Who or what is Cassiopeia?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/6237/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17/rand-althor)
- *add entries in the form `https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)`*

---

The **highest-voted** of these is [In the "Neverending Story", what judgement do Falkor and Atreyu make of the Childlike Empress?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/5973/17), with a score of **9** at the end of the month.

The **most viewed** is [In the "Neverending Story", what judgement do Falkor and Atreyu make of the Childlike Empress?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/5973/17), with approximately **80** views during the month.

---

Of the 10 questions listed above, two were about [momo](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/momo), seven about [the-neverending-story](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-neverending-story), and one inspired by [jim-button-luke-the-engine-driver](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jim-button-luke-the-engine-driver).