# Announcing the April 2018 Topic Challenge: “Look Who's Back”

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

In accordance with our [meta agreement](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/571/17) to have topic challenges, and since the [list of suggestions](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/596/17) has a single highest-voted entry as March nears its end, it's time to announce the next topic challenge! Throughout **April 2018**, our topic challenge, [proposed](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/616/17) by [fi12](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/users/123/fi12), will be

> ### **[*Look Who's Back*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look_Who%27s_Back), by Timur Vermes**.

As with the previous announcements, I'm posting this before the actual start of the challenge, so that people have time to prepare, get a copy of the book to start reading, and so forth. The topic challenge itself will start on the 1st of April (but no fool questions!)

### The topic challenge has begun - you can get posting now!

---

**What's a topic challenge?**

See the meta posts linked above, and also [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/278659). In short, during April we should all read *Look Who's Back* and try to post thoughtful and interesting questions about it.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, but those who participate will be forever remembered in the [annals](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1015/17) of our history. And of course it goes without saying that questions on other works are more than welcome during April too; they just won't count as part of this topic challenge.

**How can I take part?**

By getting hold of the book, in whatever language you prefer, and asking good questions about it. (It's been translated into English and many other languages, but it's not old enough to be out of copyright.) These questions should be tagged with [look-whos-back](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/look-whos-back) and [timur-vermes](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/timur-vermes) and [german-literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/german-literature), and other tags if applicable. We'll keep a list of all such questions in an answer to this meta post.

**What's next?**

- Vote [here](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/596/17) for the next topic challenge, or propose your own!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **List of [all questions posted](https://literature.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=[look-whos-back]%20created%3a2018-04-01..2018-04-30%20is%3aquestion) as part of the April 2018 Topic Challenge**

- [How thoroughly was "Look Who's Back" researched?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/6458/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17)

At the end of the month, it had a score of **0** and approximately **1** view.

No answers were submitted during the topic challenge.

***Let's try to do better next time!***