# Announcing the May 2018 topic challenge: Ursula K. Le Guin

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

In accordance with our [meta agreement](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/571/17) to have topic challenges, and since the [list of suggestions](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/596/17) has a single highest-voted entry at the end of April, it's time to announce the next topic challenge! Throughout **May 2018**, our topic challenge, [proposed](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/994/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/users/17), will be

> ### the works of the author **[Ursula K. Le Guin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ursula_K._Le_Guin)** (1929-2018).

---

**What's a topic challenge?**

See the meta posts linked above, and also [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/278659). In short, during May we should all read stories by Ursula le Guin and try to post thoughtful and interesting questions about them.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, but those who participate will be forever remembered in the [annals](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1026/17) of our history. And of course it goes without saying that questions on other works are more than welcome during May too; they just won't count as part of this topic challenge.

**How can I take part?**

By getting hold of [any Le Guin story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ursula_K._Le_Guin_bibliography), in whatever language you prefer, and asking good questions about it. These questions should be tagged with [ursula-le-guin](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ursula-le-guin), and either [short-stories](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-stories) or the appropriate novel/series tag, and other tags if applicable. We'll keep a list of all such questions in an answer to this meta post.

**What's next?**

- Vote [here](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/596/17) for the next topic challenge, or propose your own!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**List of [all questions posted](https://literature.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=[ursula-le-guin]%20created%3a2018-05-01..2018-05-31%20is%3aquestion) as part of the May 2018 Topic Challenge**

- [Why could Dragons lie in Old Speech?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/6570/why-could-dragons-lie-in-old-speech) by [EJoshuaS](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/ejoshuas)
- [How did Ursula Le Guin translate the Tao Te Ching / Dao De Jing?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/6580/17) by [Christophe Strobbe](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/christophe-strobbe)
- [Are wizard and mage used interchangeably in Le Guin's Earthsea series?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/6592/17) by [Christophe Strobbe](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/christophe-strobbe)
- [When did Ursula (K) Le Guin use the K on her books and when not?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/6640/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17/)
- [Why were Ogion's teaching methods so different than the teaching methods in Roke?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/6644/why-were-ogions-teaching-methods-so-different-than-the-teaching-methods-in-roke) by [EJoshuaS](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/ejoshuas)
- [Why was Ogion troubled by the name of the ship that Ged took to Roke?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/6645/why-was-ogion-troubled-by-the-name-of-the-ship-that-ged-took-to-roke) by [EJoshuaS](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/ejoshuas)
- [How did one become a Wizard in A Wizard of Earthsea?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/6646/how-did-one-become-a-wizard-in-a-wizard-of-earthsea) by [EJoshuaS](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/793/ejoshuas)
- [Is there a specific order to read Ursula Le Guin's novels and stories?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/6677/2191) by [Christophe Strobbe](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/christophe-strobbe)

---

The **highest-voted** of these is [How did Ursula Le Guin translate the Tao Te Ching / Dao De Jing?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/6580/how-did-ursula-le-guin-translate-the-tao-te-ching-dao-de-jing), with a score of **6** at the end of the month.

The **most viewed** is [Why could Dragons lie in Old Speech?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/6570/why-could-dragons-lie-in-old-speech), with approximately **75** views during the month.

**Eight answers** were submitted during the topic challenge. Only the last question received no answer.