# Announcing the June 2018 topic challenge: Their Eyes Were Watching God

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

In accordance with our [meta agreement](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/571/17) to have topic challenges, and since the [list of suggestions](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/596/17) has a single highest-voted entry at the end of May, it's time to announce the next topic challenge! Throughout **June 2018**, our topic challenge, [proposed](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/598/17) by [Hamlet/user111](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/users/111), will be

> ### [*Their Eyes Were Watching God*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Their_Eyes_Were_Watching_God) by Zora Neale Hurston.

---

**What's a topic challenge?**

See the meta posts linked above, and also [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/278659). In short, during June we should all read *Their Eyes Were Watching God* and try to post thoughtful and interesting questions about it.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, but those who participate will be forever remembered in the [annals](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1035/17) of our history. And of course it goes without saying that questions on other works are more than welcome during June too; they just won't count as part of this topic challenge.

**How can I take part?**

By getting hold of the book, in whatever language you prefer, and asking good questions about it. Having been published in 1937, I believe it's now out of copyright and so it's OK to link [an online full-text](https://archive.org/stream/TheirEyesWereWatchingGodFullBookPDF/Their+Eyes+Were+Watching+God+Full+Book+PDF_djvu.txt). These questions should be tagged with [their-eyes-were-watching-god](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/their-eyes-were-watching-god) and [zora-neale-hurston](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zora-neale-hurston), and other tags if applicable. We'll keep a list of all such questions in an answer to this meta post.

**What's next?**

- Vote [here](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/596/17) for the next topic challenge, or propose your own!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **List of [all questions posted](https://literature.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=[their-eyes-were-watching-god]%20created%3a2018-06-01..2018-06-30%20is%3aquestion) as part of the June 2018 Topic Challenge**

- [Was the Eatonville of "Their Eyes Were Watching God" modeled exactly on the real town of the same name or simply inspired by it?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/6698/58) by [Mithrandir](https://literature.stackexchange.com/u/58)
- [Is the beginning of "Their Eyes Were Watching God" drawing a comparison of men and women?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/6704/17) by [Mithrandir](https://literature.stackexchange.com/u/58)

---

The **highest-voted** and **most viewed** of these is [Is the beginning of "Their Eyes Were Watching God" drawing a comparison of men and women?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/6704/17) by [Mithrandir](https://literature.stackexchange.com/u/58), with a score of **2** at the end of the month and approximately **30** views during the month.

**One answer** was submitted during the topic challenge.