# Announcing the July 2018 reading challenge: "The Assault"

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

July has begun, and it is time to announce this month's reading challenge, which is...

> ### [*The Assault*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Assault) by Harry Mulisch

[suggested](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/731/11) by [Martin Tournoij](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1485/martin-tournoij).

#### What is a topic challenge?

The topic challenges [were started](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/571/do-we-want-something-akin-to-topic-challenges-for-books-outside-our-bailiwick-t) to acquaint the users with literature they may not have been familiar with otherwise. During this month we read the book, and try to post questions about it.

#### How does the topic challenge work?

If you have a question about the book, simply post it and tag it with [the-assault](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-assault), [harry-mulisch](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-mulisch), and [dutch-literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dutch-literature).

Participation is not obligatory, but those who participate will be listed right here. Needless to say, questions on other books are always welcome as well - they just don't count as a part of *this* topic challenge.

#### What's next?

Read the book, and ask questions about it! Also, don't forget to vote for the next challenge [here](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/596/suggest-your-lit-se-reading-challenges-here), or propose your own!

Comment: Answer acceptance here? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**List of all questions posted as part of the July 2018 topic challenge**:

- [Did Harry Mulisch plagiarise other works in his novel The Assault / De aanslag?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/6909/2191) by [Christophe Strobbe](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2191/christophe-strobbe)
- [Relevance of Pliny the Younger quote in The Assault (De aanslag) by Harry Mulisch?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/8035/2191) by [Christophe Strobbe](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2191/christophe-strobbe)

---

The **highest-voted** and **most viewed** of these is [Did Harry Mulisch plagiarise other works in his novel The Assault / De aanslag?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/6909/2191) by [Christophe Strobbe](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2191/christophe-strobbe), with a score of **5** at the end of the month and approximately **30** views during the month.

**One answer** was submitted during the topic challenge (the second question was self-answered).