# Announcing the September 2018 topic challenge: Elif Şafak

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

### The September topic challenge is now ongoing!

In accordance with our [meta agreement](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/571/17) to have topic challenges, and since the [list of suggestions](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/596/17) has a single highest-voted entry as August comes to an end, it's time to announce the next topic challenge! Throughout **September 2018**, our topic challenge, [proposed](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/751/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17), will be

> ### the works of [Elif Şafak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elif_%C5%9Eafak).

---

**What's a topic challenge?**

See the meta posts linked above, and also [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/278659). In short, during September we should all read Elif Şafak stories and try to post thoughtful and interesting questions about them.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, but those who participate will be forever remembered in the [annals](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1081/17) of our history. And of course it goes without saying that questions on other works are more than welcome during September too; they just won't count as part of this topic challenge.

**How can I take part?**

By getting hold of stories written by Elif Şafak, in whatever language you prefer, and asking good questions about them. These questions should be tagged with [elif-safak](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elif-safak), and either a title tag (for long works such as novels) or the [short-stories](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-stories) tag, and other tags if applicable. We'll keep a list of all such questions in an answer to this meta post. Examples of Elif Şafak stories:

- *Honour* | [*İskender*](https://tr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%B0skender_(roman)), a novel which (I think) has been recommended to me IRL. [Review](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2012/apr/20/honour-elif-shafak-review).
- "Writing Amidst the Ruins", a short story. [You can hear her read it online.](https://themoth.org/stories/writing-amidst-the-ruins)
- *The Bastard of Istanbul* | *Baba ve Piç*, a novel exploring Turkish and Armenian culture and history through a family of women connected to both countries. [Summary and 9-page excerpt.](https://www.bookbrowse.com/excerpts/index.cfm/book_number/1944/the-bastard-of-istanbul)
- *Forty Rules of Love*, a novel which [has already been asked about](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/1666/17) on this site. [Review.](https://www.theguardian.com/childrens-books-site/2014/dec/05/review-elif-shafak-forty-rules-of-love)
- <sub>*[feel free to add to this list; Wikipedia has [her bibliography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elif_Shafak#Bibliography)]*</sub>

**What's next?**

- Vote [here](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/596/17) for the next topic challenge, or propose your own!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **List of [all questions posted](https://literature.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=[elif-safak]%20created%3a2018-09-01..2018-09-30%20is%3aquestion) in the September 2018 Topic Challenge**

- [Why are the chapters in The Bastard of Istanbul named after ingredients of ashure?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/8428/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17)
- [Why was The Bastard of Istanbul translated into Turkish as "Father and Bastard"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/8430/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17)
- [How do the letters S, U, F, I symbolise the stages of Aziz's life?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/8452/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17)
- [Why did Shams refuse to sleep with Kimya?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/8458/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17)
- [Was The Forty Rules of Love originally written in Turkish or in English?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/8470/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17)
- [Why include the frame story in The Forty Rules of Love?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/8525/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17)
- [The Forty Rules of Love - what kind of "love"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/8530/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17)
- *add entries in the form `https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)`*

---

The **highest-voted** of these was [Why are the chapters in The Bastard of Istanbul named after ingredients of ashure?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/8428/17), with a score of **3** at the end of the month.

The **most viewed** was [Was The Forty Rules of Love originally written in Turkish or in English?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/8470/17), with approximately **55** views during the month.

**Two answers** were submitted during the topic challenge (both on the [same question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/8470/2191)).

<sub>*Apparently this topic wasn't of very broad interest among site members ... `:-/`*</sub>