# Announcing the October 2018 Topic Challenge: Robert Hayden

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

For this month's challenge, we move from Turkey to the USA to focus on

> **the poems of [Robert Hayden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Hayden)**

[suggested](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/619/2191) by [BESW](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/users/151).

Robert Hayden (1913 – 1980)  was the first African-American writer to hold the office of [Consultant in Poetry to the Library of Congress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Poet_Laureate). A few of his poems can be found on [Poets.org](https://www.poets.org/poetsorg/poet/robert-hayden) or on [PoetryFoundation.org](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poets/robert-hayden). See also the article [About Hayden's Life and Career](http://www.english.illinois.edu/Maps/poets/g_l/hayden/life.htm) by Mark A. Sanders, the [Library of Congress](https://www.loc.gov/item/n79046298/robert-hayden-1913-1980/) (which as a few audio recordings of Hayden reading his own poems) and this edition of his [*Collected Poems*](http://books.wwnorton.com/books/978-0-87140-679-8/).

#### What is a topic challenge?

The topic challenges [were started](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/571/do-we-want-something-akin-to-topic-challenges-for-books-outside-our-bailiwick-t) to acquaint the users with literature they may not have been familiar with otherwise. During this month we read the book(s), and try to post questions about it (or them).

#### How does the topic challenge work?

If you have a question about a poem, ask it on the main site, tagging it with [poetry](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry) and [robert-hayden](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robert-hayden).

Participation is not obligatory, but those who participate will be listed right here. Needless to say, questions on other books are always welcome as well - they just don't count as a part of *this* topic challenge.

#### What's next?

Read the author's works, and ask questions about them! Also, don't forget to vote for the [next challenge](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/596/suggest-your-lit-se-reading-challenges-here), or propose your own!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**List of [all questions posted](https://literature.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=[robert-hayden]%20created%3a2018-10-01..2018-10-31%20is%3aquestion) in the October 2018 Topic Challenge**

- [What does flying represent in "O Daedalus, Fly Away Home"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/8538) by [Benjamin](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/143)
- [Why is God a "harshener"? What does this mean?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/8547) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17)

---

The **highest-voted** and **most viewed** of these was [Why is God a "harshener"? What does this mean?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/8547), with a score of **4** at the end of the month and approximately **25** views during the month.

**One answer** was submitted during the topic challenge.