# Announcing the November 2018 topic challenge: the Kalevala

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

In accordance with our [meta agreement](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/571/17) to have topic challenges, and since the [list of suggestions](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/596/17) has a single highest-voted entry at the start of this month, it's time to announce the next topic challenge! Throughout **November 2018**, our topic challenge, [proposed](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1013/17) by [heather](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/1982), will be

> ### [*The Kalevala*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalevala).

---

**What's a topic challenge?**

See the meta posts linked above, and also [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/278659). In short, during November we should all try to read at least some part of the Kalevala and post thoughtful and interesting questions about it.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, but those who participate will be forever remembered in the [annals](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1099/17) of our history. And of course it goes without saying that questions on other works are more than welcome during November too; they just won't count as part of this topic challenge.

**How can I take part?**

By getting hold of the Kalevala, in whatever language you prefer, and asking good questions about it. These questions should be tagged with [the-kalevala](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-kalevala) and [finnish-literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finnish-literature), and other tags if applicable. We'll keep a list of all such questions in an answer to this meta post.

- The best English version I've found freely available online is [Crawford's translation at the Sacred Texts site](http://www.sacred-texts.com/neu/kveng/index.htm). The same website also has the text [in the original Finnish](http://www.sacred-texts.com/neu/kvfin/index.htm).
- Wikipedia has a [decent list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalevala#Further_reading) of translations, retellings, and further reading relevant to the Kalevala. At least some of this material is also freely available online.

**What's next?**

- Vote [here](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/596/17) for the next topic challenge, or propose your own!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **List of [all questions posted](https://literature.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5Bthe-kalevala%5D%20created%3a2018-11-01..2018-11-30%20is%3aquestion) in the November 2018 Topic Challenge**

- [What is a "proem", and why was this word used in the translation of the Kalevala?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/8729/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17/rand-althor) (4 net upvotes; ca. 59 views; 1 answer)
- [Does the Kalevala rely on the concepts of good and evil?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/8732/does-the-kalevala-rely-on-the-concepts-of-good-and-evil) by [Christophe Strobbe](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/christophe-strobbe) (3 net upvotes; ca. 24 views; no answers)
- [How are we supposed to know that Wainamoinen is the son?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/8754/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17/rand-althor) (3 net upvotes; 34 views; no answers)
- [How is Wainamoinen "old" at the start of the second Rune?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/8829/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17/rand-althor) (2 net upvotes; 58 views; 3 answers)
- *add entries in the form `https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)`*

---

The **highest-voted** of these is *[What is a "proem", and why was this word used in the translation of the Kalevala?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/8729/17)*, with a score of *4* at the end of the month.

The **most viewed** is *[What is a "proem", and why was this word used in the translation of the Kalevala?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/8729/17)*, with approximately *59* views during the month.

**Four answers** were submitted during the topic challenge, including three answers to the last question.