# Announcing the December 2018 reading challenge: Darcie Little Badger

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

In accordance with our [meta agreement](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/571/17) to have topic challenges, and since the [list of suggestions](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/596/17) has a single highest-voted entry at the start of this month, it's time to announce the next topic challenge! Throughout **December 2018**, our topic challenge, [proposed](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1037/2191) by [Mithrandir](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/users/58/mithrandir), will be

> ### the works of [Darcie Little Badger](https://darcielittlebadger.wordpress.com/about/).

---

**What's a topic challenge?**

See the meta posts linked above, and also [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/278659). In short, during December we should all try to read at least one of Darcie Little Badger's works and post thoughtful and interesting questions about it.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, but those who participate will be forever remembered in the [annals](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1099/17) of our history. And of course it goes without saying that questions on other works are more than welcome during November too; they just won't count as part of this topic challenge.

**How can I take part?**

By getting hold of the stories or other works by Darcie Little Badger and asking good questions about them. These questions should be tagged with [darcie-little-badger](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/darcie-little-badger), and other tags if applicable. We'll keep a list of all such questions in an answer to this meta post.

- The author's Wordpress site has a list of [her published stories](https://darcielittlebadger.wordpress.com/my-short-stories/), some of which are available online.
- The same site also has a short list of [Blog-Published Prose and Poetry](https://darcielittlebadger.wordpress.com/blog-published-prose-and-poetry/).

**What's next?**

- Vote [here](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/596/2191) for the next topic challenge, or propose your own!

Comment: Some handy links to free online works: "[The Famine King](https://bit.ly/2rhcjMt)"; "[Black, Their Regalia](https://bit.ly/2FXn5Sk)"; "[When Whales Fall](https://bit.ly/2BOgdCH)"; "[Nkásht íí](http://www.strangehorizons.com/2014/20141215/Willowbee-f.shtml)"; "[To Sleep](https://darcielittlebadger.wordpress.com/2014/12/19/to-sleep/)"; "[Robo-Liopleurodon!](https://robotdinosaurfiction.com/tag/darcie-little-badger/)"; "[The Whalebone Parrot](http://thedarkmagazine.com/the-whalebone-parrot/)"; "[Owl vs. the Neighborhood Watch](http://strangehorizons.com/fiction/owl-vs-the-neighborhood-watch/)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**List of [all questions posted](https://literature.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=[darcie-little-badger]%20created%3a2018-12-01..2018-12-31%20is%3aquestion) in the December 2018 Topic Challenge**

- [Is Irene actually delusional in "The Famine King"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/8878/17) by [Mithrandir](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/58/mithrandir) (O votes, 25 views)
- [What is the language which appears in "The Whalebone Parrot"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/8898/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17/rand-althor) (0 votes, 38 views)
- [How is the possession by "The Whalebone Parrot" related to Loretta's Native American identity?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/8907/17) by [Cahir Mawr Dyffryn æp Ceallach](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/50/cahir-mawr-dyffryn-%c3%a6p-ceallach) (3 votes, 26 views)
- [Does "The Whalebone Parrot" draw inspiration from any specific Apache sources?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/8914/17) by [Mithrandir](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/58/mithrandir) (1 vote, 19 views)

---

The **highest-voted** of these is *[How is the possession by "The Whalebone Parrot" related to Loretta's Native American identity?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/8907/17)*, with a score of *3* at the end of the month.

The **most viewed** is *[What is the language which appears in "The Whalebone Parrot"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/8898/17)*, with approximately *38* views during the month.

**One answer** was submitted during the topic challenge (self-answered question).