# Announcing the March 2019 reading challenge: Release the Sun, by William Sears

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

In accordance with our [meta agreement](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/571/2191) to have topic challenges, and since the [list of suggestions](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/596/2191) has a single highest-voted entry at the start of this month (+10, -5), it is time to announce the next topic challenge! Throughout **March 2019**, our topic challenge, [proposed](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/617/2191) by [BESW](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/users/151), will be

> ### *Release the Sun* by [William Sears (Bahá'í)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Sears_(Bah%C3%A1%27%C3%AD)).

---

**What's a topic challenge?**

See the meta posts linked above, and also [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/340816). In short, during March we should all try to read *Release the Sun* and post thoughtful and interesting questions about it.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, but those who participate will be forever remembered in the [annals](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1099/2191) of our history. And of course it goes without saying that questions on other works are more than welcome during March too; they just won't count as part of this topic challenge.

**How can I take part?**

By getting hold of the book *Release the Sun* and asking good questions about them. These questions should be tagged with [release-the-sun](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/release-the-sun) and [william-sears](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/william-sears), and other tags if applicable. We'll keep a list of all such questions in an answer to this meta post.

Below is BESW's presentation of the work:

> *Release the Sun,* by [William Sears](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Sears_(Bah%C3%A1%27%C3%AD)), is a narrative account of historical events surrounding the life and death of The Báb, a religious figure in 19th-century Persia and one of the three central figures of the [Bahá'í Faith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bah%C3%A1%27%C3%AD_Faith).
>
> Sears wrote *Release the Sun* in the mid 20th century, a time the Bahá'í Faith was rapidly expanding worldwide. Because the most authoritative text describing The Báb and his followers, *The Dawn-Breakers*, was considered nigh impenetrable without a thorough understanding of Persian history and culture, Sears (an American television and radio professional) wanted to provide a more accessible way for new Bahá'ís to learn about the early days of their religion.
>
> Sears makes no pretense toward neutrality in his depiction of events; he's quite upfront about why the book exists and what effect he wants to have on its target audience--but simultaneously *Release the Sun* (and its source material in *The Dawn-Breakers* and *God Passes By*) claims to be faithful to historical records and first-hand accounts.
>
> It's an amazing period in history, and there's lots of good potential for close reading AND research-based questions here. Culture, original sources, issues of translation, and then the whole subject of analysing how and why Sears made the choices he did to convey a complex culture for people unfamiliar with it--what he explains, what he leaves out, and so forth. Not to mention getting into the narration of historical events with a particular agenda from the author and how/whether it succeeds, and the role of the book in the Bahá'í community over the last fifty-plus years.

**What's next?**

- Vote [here](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/596/2191) for the next topic challenge, or propose your own!

Comment: To preserve info from the comments on the proposal: online resources include [the official repository with the most up-to-date translations](http://www.bahai.org/library/) and [a older and clunkier site with a more searchable interface](http://reference.bahai.org/) and [a third, less official, site which may have some useful info](http://www.sacred-texts.com/bhi/index.htm), as well as [the full text of *Release the Sun* freely available online](https://bahai-library.com/sears_release_sun)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, no questions related to William Sears' *Release the Sun* were posted during the topic challenge. I hope we'll do better with the next one.