# Announcing the February–March 2020 topic challenge: Haruki Murakami

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

In accordance with our [meta agreement to have topic challenges](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/571/2191)
and a later [meta agreement to have topic challenges lasting for two months](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1175/2191)
that overlap by one month, it is time to announce the February–March 2020 topic challenge.

Based on the number of votes (+6, -2), the second topic challenge of the year 2020 will be

> **Haruki Murakami**

---

**What's a topic challenge?**

See the meta posts linked above, and also [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/340816).
In short, during February and March 2020 we should all try to read one or more works by [**Haruki Murakami (村上 春樹)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haruki_Murakami).

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, but those who participate will be forever remembered in the [annals](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1099/2191) of our history.
And of course it goes without saying that questions on other works are more than welcome during June too; they just won't count as part of this topic challenge.

**How can I take part?**

By getting hold of one of the works of Haruki Murakami and asking good questions about these works.
These questions should be tagged with [haruki-murakami](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haruki-murakami) and [japanese-literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/japanese-literature).
We'll keep a list of all such questions in an answer to this meta post.

Below is the original presentation of this topic challenge, which contains several reading suggestions:

> [Haruki Murakami](http://www.harukimurakami.com/) is a Japanese writer. His books and stories have been bestsellers in Japan as well as internationally, with his work being translated into [50](https://www.curtisbrown.co.uk/news/haruki-marukami-now-available-in-50-languages) languages. His work has received numerous awards, including the World Fantasy Award, the Frank O'Connor International Short Story Award, the Franz Kafka Prize, and the Jerusalem Prize. Steven Poole of The Guardian [praised](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2000/may/27/fiction.harukimurakami) Murakami as "among the world's greatest living novelists".
>
> **Why must one read Murakami?**
>
> His work is surreal and melancholic, with recurrent themes of alienation and loneliness. What motivates me to read his works is the open-to-interpretation endings he gives to his stories.
>
> **Murakami's notable works**
>
> 1. A Wild Sheep Chase (1982)
> 2. Norwegian Wood (1987)
> 3. The Wind-Up Bird Chronicle (1994–95)
> 4. Kafka on the Shore (2002)
> 5. 1Q84 (2009–10)
>
> **Works by Murakami that are available for free:**
>
> 1. [Birthday Girl](https://harpers.org/archive/2003/07/birthday-girl/): a short story
> 2. He is a regular [contributor](https://www.newyorker.com/contributors/haruki-murakami) to *The New Yorker*, where he publishes short stories from time to time.

**What's next?**

- Vote [here](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/596/2191) for the next topic challenge (March–April), or propose your own!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [What was her wish in Haruki Murakami's "Birthday Girl"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/12494/) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/users/17/) (11.03.2020).
- [Who is the second narrator character in Haruki Murakami's "Birthday Girl"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/12495/) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/users/17/) (11.03.2020).
- [How many "Little People" are in the story-in-the-story in 1Q84?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/12527/) by [Peter Shor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/1152/) (15.03.2020).
- ["That’s because you’ve already made your wish." What does it mean?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/13593/) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/users/17/) (31.03.2020).

---

The **highest-voted** and **most-viewed** of these is [How many "Little People" are in the story-in-the-story in 1Q84?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/12527/) by [Peter Shor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/1152/), with a score of **4** and approximately **32** views at the end of March.