# Announcing the April–May 2020 topic challenge: The Stranger / Meursault

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

In accordance with our [meta agreement to have topic challenges](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/571/2191)
and a later [meta agreement to have topic challenges lasting for two months](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1175/2191)
that overlap by one month, it is time to announce the April–May 2020 topic challenge.

Based on the number of votes, the third topic challenge of the year 2020 will be

> **The Stranger / Meursault**

---

**What's a topic challenge?**

See the meta posts linked above, and also [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/340816).
In short, during April–May 2020 we should all try to read Albert Camus' novel [*L'Étranger / The Stranger*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Stranger_(Camus_novel)) and/or other works of literature that were inspired by it.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, but those who participate will be forever remembered in the [annals](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1099/2191) of our history.
And of course it goes without saying that questions on other works are more than welcome during April and May too; they just won't count as part of this topic challenge.

**How can I take part?**

By getting hold of Camus's novel *The Stranger* or another work inspired by it and asking good questions about these works.
Questions about *The Stranger* should be tagged with [the-stranger](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-stranger), [albert-camus](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/albert-camus) and [french-literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/french-literature). Questions about other works will require other tags.
We'll keep a list of all such questions in an answer to this meta post.

Below is the original presentation of this topic challenge:

> Albert Camus' novel [*L'Étranger / The Stranger*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Stranger_(Camus_novel)) has inspired other artists. The topic challenge would consist in posting and answering questions about such works. The English Wikipedia article mentions a few songs that are relevant; the [French Wikipedia article](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27%C3%89tranger) mentions a few other ones.
>
> The most interesting work inspired by *L'Étranger* may be [Kamel Daoud's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamel_Daoud) novel [*Meursault, contre-enquête* / *The Meursault Investigation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Meursault_Investigation) (2013); its story is told from the point of view of Harun, the brother of the Arab killed by Meursault.
>
> Questions about Camus's novel *L'Étranger* would also count for this challenge. (The [French version of *L'Étranger*](https://www.fadedpage.com/showbook.php?pid=20150715) is available online.)

Another novel inspired by *The Stranger* is Salim Bachi's *Le Dernier Été d’un jeune homme* (Flammarion, 2013).

**What's next?**

- Vote [here](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/596/2191) for the next topic challenge (May–June), or propose your own!

---

**Update**: An excerpt of the English translation of Daoud's novel was published in [*The New Yorker* in March 2015](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2015/04/06/musa).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- *add entries in the form `https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)`*
- [What is Meursault's problem with the heat?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/14113/17) by [Mithical](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/58/mithical) (02.05.2020)
- [Is Marie's comment based on the existence of a two-tier justice system in French Algeria?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/14114/) by [Tsundoku](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2191/) (02.05.2020)
- [Why would Maman ask for a religious burial?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/14147/58) by [Mithical](https://literature.stackexchange.com/u/58) (04.05.2020)
- [Is Meursault bothered that he doesn't know what day Maman died?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/14192/58) by [Mithical](https://literature.stackexchange.com/u/58) (06.05.2020)
- [How is the Czechoslovak traveler's story relevant to The Stranger as a whole?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/14193/) by [Tsundoku](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2191/) (06.05.2020)
- [In which interview did Camus say that Meursault is the only Christ we deserved?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/14236/) by [Tsundoku](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2191/) (08.05.2020)
- [How does The Meursault Investigation reference The Fall?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/14284/2191) by [Tsundoku](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2191/) (11.05.2020)
- [To what extent are the stylistic devices in Death of a Salesman and The Stranger similar?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/14445/17) by [djJjjj](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/10152/djjjjj) (27.05.2020)
- [What is the significance of the names Mersault and Meursault?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/14462/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17) (30.05.2020)

---

The **highest-voted** of these are [Why would Maman ask for a religious burial?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/14147/17) and [How is the Czechoslovak traveler's story relevant to The Stranger as a whole?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/14193/17) and [In which interview did Camus say that Meursault is the only Christ we deserved?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/14236/17), each with a score of **3** at the end of May.

The **most viewed** is [To what extent are the stylistic devices in Death of a Salesman and The Stranger similar?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/14445/17), with approximately **100** views by the end of May.

Six of the nine questions received an answer. The most-viewed question was closed soon after it was posted and was still closed at the end of May.