# Announcing the January 2019 topic challenge: Lu Xun

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

Happy new year to Literature SE!

In accordance with our [meta agreement](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/571/17) to have topic challenges, and since the [list of suggestions](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/596/17) has a single highest-voted entry at the start of this month, it's time to announce the next topic challenge! Throughout **January 2019**, our topic challenge, [proposed](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1069/17) by [Christophe Strobbe](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191), will be

> ### [*Lu Xun / 鲁迅*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lu_Xun).

---

**What's a topic challenge?**

See the meta posts linked above, and also [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/278659). In short, during January we should all try to read or learn about some works of Lu Xun and post thoughtful and interesting questions about them.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, but those who participate will be forever remembered in the [annals](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1111/17) of our history. And of course it goes without saying that questions on other works are more than welcome during January too; they just won't count as part of this topic challenge.

**How can I take part?**

By getting hold of Lu Xun books, in whatever language you prefer, and asking good questions about them. These questions should be tagged with [lu-xun](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lu-xun) and [chinese-literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chinese-literature), and whatever individual-work tags or other tags are applicable. We'll keep a list of all such questions in an answer to this meta post.

Further information (copied from Christophe's original proposal):

> Below are just a few of his most famous [stories](http://afe.easia.columbia.edu/special/china_1900_luxun.htm):
>
> - [A Madman's Diary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Madman%27s_Diary),
> - [Kong Yiji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kong_Yiji),
> - [A Storm in a Teacup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Storm_in_a_Teacup_(Lu_Xun)),
> - [The Story of Hair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Story_of_Hair),
> - [The True Story of Ah Q](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_True_Story_of_Ah_Q) (a must-read for anyone studying Chinese culture or history).
>
> For [English translations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lu_Xun#Translations_into_English), see for example,
>
> - [The Real Story of Ah-Q and Other Tales of China: The Complete Fiction of Lu Xun](https://www.penguin.co.uk/books/35612/the-real-story-of-ah-q-and-other-tales-of-china/), translated by Julia Lovell (Penguin, 2009).
> - [Jottings under Lamplight](http://www.hup.harvard.edu/catalog.php?isbn=9780674744257) (Harvard University Press, 2017).
>
> There are also [French translations](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lu_Xun_(%C3%A9crivain)#Principales_traductions_des_%C5%93uvres), [German translations](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lu_Xun#Werke_auf_Deutsch_und_Literatur) etc.
>
> Some online stories:
>
> - [Call to Arms](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:Call_to_Arms_(Lu_Xun)/A_Madman%27s_Diary)  (Chinese and English translation side by side, on Wikisource);
> - [Reference Archive: Lu Xun (Lu Hsun)](https://www.marxists.org/archive/lu-xun/index.htm) at marxists.org;
> - [Selected Stories of Lu Hsun](http://www.coldbacon.com/writing/luxun-calltoarms.html) (Translated by Yang Hsien-yi and Gladys Yang);
> - [Lu Xun on Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/author/26193) (in Chinese).

**What's next?**

- Vote [here](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/596/17) for the next topic challenge, or propose your own!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **List of [all questions posted](https://literature.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=[lu-xun]%20created%3a2019-01-01..2019-01-31%20is%3aquestion) in the January 2019 Topic Challenge**

- [Source of comment that Ah Qs are now running China (Lu Xun, 1930s)](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/9073/) by [Christophe Strobbe](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/christophe-strobbe) (0 votes, 18 views)
- [How did Lu Xun choose his pen name?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/9078/) by [Christophe Strobbe](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/christophe-strobbe) (2 votes, 67 views)
- [Where is the wordplay in the names Zhao Guiweng and Gu Jiu?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/9097/17) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17/rand-althor) (2 votes, 53 views)

---

The **highest-voted** of these are *[How did Lu Xun choose his pen name?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/9078/)* and *[Where is the wordplay in the names Zhao Guiweng and Gu Jiu?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/9097/17)*, with a score of *2* by the end of the month.

The **most viewed** is *[How did Lu Xun choose his pen name?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/9078/)*, with approximately *65* views by the end of the month.

**Two answers** were submitted during the topic challenge (excluding one answer that was deleted by its author before the end of the month).