# Announcing the February 2019 topic challenge: Miroslav Krleža

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

In accordance with our [meta agreement](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/571/58) to have topic challenges, and since the [list of suggestions](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/596/58) has a single highest-voted entry at the start of this month, it's time to announce the next topic challenge! Throughout **February 2019**, our topic challenge, [proposed](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1001/58) by [Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17), will be

> ### [Miroslav Krleža](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miroslav_Krle%C5%BEa).

---

**What's a topic challenge?**

See the meta posts linked above, and also [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/). In short, during February we should all try to read or learn about some works of Miroslav Krleža and post thoughtful and interesting questions about them.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, but those who participate will be forever remembered in the annals of our history. And of course it goes without saying that questions on other works are more than welcome during February too; they just won't count as part of this topic challenge.

**How can I take part?**

By getting hold of Miroslav Krleža books, in whatever language you prefer, and asking good questions about them. These questions should be tagged with [miroslav-krleza](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/miroslav-krleza) and [croatian-literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/croatian-literature), and whatever individual-work tags or other tags are applicable. We'll keep a list of all such questions in an answer to this meta post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no questions related to Miroslav Krleža's life or works were posted during the topic challenge. I hope we'll do better with the next one.