# Announcing the May 2019 topic challenge: "My Uncle Napoleon"

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

In accordance with our [meta agreement](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/571/58) to have topic challenges, and since the [list of suggestions](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/596/58) has a single highest-voted entry as April draws to a close, it's time to announce the next topic challenge! Throughout **May 2019**, our topic challenge, [proposed](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/752/58) by [BESW](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/users/151/), will be

> ## *My Uncle Napoleon*, by Iraj Pezeshkzad
>
> (also called *Dear Uncle Napoleon*)

---

**What's a topic challenge?**

See the meta posts linked above, and also [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/). In short, during May we should all read *Mu Uncle Napoleon* and try to post thoughtful and interesting questions about it.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, but those who participate will be forever remembered in the annals of our history. And of course it goes without saying that questions on other works are more than welcome during May too; they just won't count as part of this topic challenge.

**How can I take part?**

By getting hold of the book, in whatever language you prefer, and asking good questions about it. These questions should be tagged with [iraj-pezeshkzad](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iraj-pezeshkzad), [my-uncle-napoleon](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/my-uncle-napoleon), and [persian-literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/persian-literature), along with other tags if applicable. We'll keep a list of all such questions in an answer to this meta post.

**What's next?**

- Vote [here](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/596/58) for the next topic challenge, or propose your own!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no questions related to Iraj Pezeshkzad's *My Uncle Napoleon* were posted during the topic challenge. I hope we'll do better with the next one.