# Best Questions & Answers from 1st Quarter of 2020

Tags: discussion, best-of

Here's the latest installment in [what's](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/676/17) now [becoming](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/785/17) a [grand](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/912/17) old [tradition](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/989/17) of [gathering](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1016/17) some [particularly](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1076/17) good [Literature](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1084/17) Q&A in [order](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1124/17) to [get](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1152/17) some [easily](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1169/17) available [links](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1216/17) to [show](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1217/17) off to people.

Since Literature has a [community-run Twitter account](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/689/17), one use for this post will be to gather links for tweeting. But it's also useful for any kind of site promotion - if we want to show off the site to literary friends, it'll be much easier if we have a list of particularly great posts to point to.

> **Please nominate some exemplary Q&A from the first quarter (Jan/Feb/Mar) of 2020**.

(Also, if you find anything from previous months, feel free to go and post answers on any of the older [best-of](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-of) posts linked above. The date of the meta answer doesn't matter - late entries are still more than welcome! - only the date of the post on main that's being nominated.)

- When choosing nominations, please remember the primary purpose: to showcase our site to people elsewhere in the hope of maybe tempting them to come here. Let's try to focus mainly on **great questions with great answers**, and perhaps also **great unanswered questions** (which we can advertise as "hey, why not come and answer this") - *not* anything with subpar answers, which will tend to give a bad impression and defeat the purpose.
- Remember that **votes don't necessarily reflect quality**, and the purpose of this is to promote quality over score. Highly-voted posts are easy to find, underappreciated gems less so.
- Getting a wide range of different stories represented in our list here would also be nice, but not strictly necessary - feel free to nominate a bunch of Q&A about the same book, if you think they're all outstanding. But don't nominate questions just because they're about your favourite book.
- Multiple nominated posts per answer here is fine.
- Feel free to nominate either some of your own posts which you're particularly proud of, or posts from other people which really impressed you.
- Ideally, some explanation of *why* the nominated questions and answers are so good would be useful - constructive feedback might give people ideas about what to aim for in the future.

Comment: Useful searches: [questions](https://literature.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=created%3a2020-01..2020-03%20is%3aq) and [answers](https://literature.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=created%3a2020-01..2020-03%20is%3aa) from 2020Q1 ordered by votes.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that 2020 Q1 answers to earlier questions are acceptable, I would like to nominate **[Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/tsundoku)'s efforts in the [epic-of-gilgamesh](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/epic-of-gilgamesh) tag**. Starting some time after our not-especially-successful [Oct-Nov 2019 topic challenge](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1194/17), he has been posting some great in-depth well-supported answers to Gilgamesh questions:

- [How can Gilgamesh be one-third man and two-thirds god?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/12206/17) (Q in Oct, A in Jan, expanded/accepted Mar)
- [Why did the gods send the flood in The Epic of Gilgamesh?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/12215/17) (Q in Nov, A in Jan)
- [What is the content of the “monkey tablet” of the Gilgamesh epic?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/12228/17) (Q in Jan, A in Mar)
- [What is the 'full' version of The Epic of Gilgamesh?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/12563/17) (Q in Apr '18, A in Mar)
- [Is there really a single “Old Babylonian version” of the Epic of Gilgamesh?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/13579/17) (Q in Dec, A in Mar)
- [Which flood story was first?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/348/17) (Q in Jan '17, A in Mar)

(Answers posted in April 2020 not included.) Several of these were posted after earlier answers had already been provided, but beat them in quality even if not yet in votes.

Furthermore, he has been carrying out edits and improvements to the Wikipedia page on the Epic of Gilgamesh, since parts of it were confusingly or mistakenly worded (prompting some of the questions on our site). It makes me very happy that our community, inspired by our topic challenges, can improve knowledge of a piece of literature in the *broader internet* as well as just this site.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to highlight two new users:

- [Goh](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/8661/goh) wrote insightful and well-argued answers on [*A Farewell to Arms*](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/12471/3003) and [*Catcher in the Rye*](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/12499/3003).
- [llywrch](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/8480/llywrch) wrote clear answers on survival of ancient texts in [Latin](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/12490/3003) and [cuneiform](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/12447/3003).