# Announcing the November–December 2022 topic challenge: Nazi Holocaust literature

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

In accordance with our [meta agreement to have topic challenges](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/571/2191)
and a later [meta agreement to have topic challenges lasting for two months and overlapping by one month](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1175/2191),
it is time to announce the November–December 2022 topic challenge.

Based on the number of votes (+8, -4), our 62nd topic challenge will be

**Nazi Holocaust literature**

This challenge covers books in a variety of languages, which is unusual for our topic challenges.

---

**What's a topic challenge?**

See the meta posts linked above, and also [this main Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/340816).
In short, during November and December 2022 you are invited to try to get hold of one of the many fictional or non-fictional works about the Holocaust and ask questions about it.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, and questions on other works are more than welcome during November and December too;
they just won't count as part of this topic challenge.

**How can I take part?**

By getting hold of one or more works based on or inspired by the Nazi Holocaust and asking good questions about it or by answering questions that have been posted as part of this challenge.
Questions about these works should be tagged with the author's name, the work's title (assuming it is a book-length publication) and its language (if it is not in English).
We'll keep a list of all such questions in an answer to this meta post.

Below is [Auden Young's](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/1982/)
[presentation](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1247/2191), which was heavily expanded by other users:

> This includes both fiction and non-fiction books - examples include
>
> - [*Night*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_(book)) by Elie Weisel
> - [*Diary of a Young Girl*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Diary_of_a_Young_Girl) by Anne Frank
> - [*Maus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maus) by Art Spiegelman (based on interviews with author's father, graphic novel)
> - Children's poems from [Terezin Concentration Camp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theresienstadt_concentration_camp#Cultural_activities_and_legacy)
> - [*The Book Thief*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Book_Thief) by Markus Zusak (fiction)
> - [*Number the Stars*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_the_Stars) by Lois Lowry (fiction/children's literature)
> - [*Milkweed*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milkweed_(novel)) by Jerry Spinelli (fiction/children's literature)
> - *Le grand voyage* (*The Long Voyage* or *The Cattle Truck*) by [Jorge Semprún](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jorge_Sempr%C3%BAn)
> - *L'Espèce humaine* (1947) by [Robert Antelme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Antelme)
> - [*Naked Among Wolves*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naked_Among_Wolves_(novel)) (German: *Nackt unter Wölfen*, 1958) by Bruno Apitz
> - *A Gypsy in Auschwitz* (1999) by [Otto Rosenberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otto_Rosenberg_(writer_and_activist))
> - [*If This Is a Man*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_This_Is_a_Man) (1947) by Primo Levi
> - *Der Totenwald* (*Forest of the dead*; 1945) by [Ernst Wiechert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernst_Wiechert)
> - the [Vrba–Wetzler report](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vrba%E2%80%93Wetzler_report) (part of the [*Auschwitz Protocols*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auschwitz_Protocols), eyewitness accounts)
> - *J'ai sauté du train* / *My Leap to Freedom* by [Odette Spingarn](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odette_Spingarn)
> - *Ihr sollt die Wahrheit erben. Die Cellistin von Auschwitz. Erinnerungen* / *Inherit the truth, 1939–1945: The documented experiences of a survivor of Auschwitz and Belsen* by [Anita Lasker-Wallfisch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anita_Lasker-Wallfisch), a surviving member of the Women's Orchestra in Auschwitz.
> - *People in Auschwitz* by Auschwitz survivor and historian [Hermann Langbein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann_Langbein)
> - [*Man's Search for Meaning*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man%27s_Search_for_Meaning) by Holocaust survivor and psychiatrist Viktor Frankl
> - *Ich war Hitlerjunge Salomon* / *I Was Hitler Youth Salomon* by [Salomon Perelman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solomon_Perel)
> - *La Jeune Fille aux yeux bleus* by Holocaust survivor and chess player [Isabelle Choko](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isabelle_Choko)
> - the works of [Tadeusz Borowski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tadeusz_Borowski)
> - *44 Months in Jasenovac* by Egon Berger, who survived the [Jasenovac concentration camp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jasenovac_concentration_camp) in the Independent State of Croatia
> - *The Choice - Poland, 1939-1945* by [Irene Eber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irene_Eber)

For comparison, you can read [Auden Young's original presentation from 2017](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/830/2191) on the first suggestions thread.

See also the following Wikipedia lists and categories:

- [List of posthumous publications of Holocaust victims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_posthumous_publications_of_Holocaust_victims)
- [List of Holocaust diarists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Holocaust_diarists)
- [Category:Personal accounts of the Holocaust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Personal_accounts_of_the_Holocaust)

**What's next?**

- [Vote for the next topic challenge](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1238/2191) or propose your own!

Comment: Just curious, why specify "the Nazi Holocaust"? That typically is implicit in the term. As Wikipedia says, "The Holocaust, also known as the Shoah, was the genocide of European Jews during World War II. Between 1941 and 1945, Nazi Germany and its collaborators systematically murdered some six million Jews across German-occupied Europe; around two-thirds of Europe's Jewish population."

Comment: I mean, yes, I know that the term "holocaust" has been used in lowercase to refer to any number of events of mass death, including the Armenian genocide, but there's not usually any ambiguity with the Holocaust in uppercase with the definite article.

Answer (score 3):

**List of all questions posted in this topic challenge**

1. [Who rebutted Raul Hilberg's allegation that Man's Search for Meaning was a deception?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/23729/2191) by [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/), 21.12.2022.
2. [When was the first time a Holocaust memoir or diary was exposed as a fraud?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/23748/) by [Tsundoku](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2191/), 22.12.2022.

---

The **highest-voted** of these is [When was the first time a Holocaust memoir or diary was exposed as a fraud?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/23748/), with a score of 4 at the end of December.

The **most viewed** is [When was the first time a Holocaust memoir or diary was exposed as a fraud?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/23748/), with approximately 58 views during the months of November and December.

Neither of the above questions received an answer.